# A question on consistency of fonts in figures and in text

Tags: plot, matlab

Suppose I output a figure of some function from Matlab, without adding the x-axis label and y-axis label. The figure is then saved as a PDF file.

Now I want to input this figure into LaTeX, and I want to

1. add the x-axis label and y-axis label;
2. add the name of the function in the figure, just near the line;

because by doing so, the fonts in the x/y-axis labels and in the figure are consistent with the main font used in the text.

Is there any method to do this?

Comment: This may be helpful: [matlab figures with latex fonts](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78478)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: This may also be helpful: [What do people use for modifying figures?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1282/what-do-people-use-for-modifying-figures)
I have had success using the `psfrag` package.