# Precompiled preamble with TikZ/Externalize

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, preamble, tikz-external

I'm using the *externalize* capability of TikZ (`external` library) to speed up compilation of my TikZ pictures (as explained in [Script to automate externalizing TikZ graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1460/script-to-automate-externalizing-tikz-graphics)).

In addition, I would like to speed up compilation by precompiling the preamble. It is explained in http://magic.aladdin.cs.cmu.edu/2007/11/02/precompiled-preamble-for-latex/ how this can be achieved.
The command for precompiling the header is:

```
pdflatex -ini -job-name="main" "&pdflatex fmt.tex\dump"
```

where `fmt.tex` contains the documentclass and package declarations, and the header is subsequently inserted into the file by having the first line say

```
%&fmt
```

Both methods by themselves work well and result in nice speed-ups. Now, I am trying to apply both methods at the same time. This gives me the following error-message during compilation:

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
    rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "figures/fmt-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalre
    aljob{fmt}\input{fmt}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'figures/fmt-fig
    ure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enab
    led system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it 
    is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply fa
    iled? Error messages can be found in 'figures/fmt-figure0.log'. If you continue
     now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
```

Note: I am compiling with option `-shell-escape` already. In addition, I precompiled the header with that option as well.

Minimal working (breaking) example:

fmt.tex - the header

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/]
```

test.tex - the main file

```
%&fmt
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, circle, minimum width=1cm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that you can place links directly into questions and answers. You don't need to use the 'add link' button. The links look the same or even better: links to other stackexchange posts will be formatted automatically.

Comment: Maybe you need to move some of the TikZ code to the dynamic preamble. The guide you linked states that everything which loads auxiliary files must not be pre-compiled, so just move the `external` library from the static to the dynamic preamble. If this doesn't work please consider to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that causes this error. Otherwise it will be difficult to fix it.

Comment: I'm doing the exact same thing here, yet all is good. Note that my `\tikzexternalize` command is in my _dynamic_ preamble. The library itself can be in the static preamble unlike with Martin said.

Comment: @remeovs: Thanks for sharing. I just meant to experiment with the position of the externalization code. Moving the library would just be the first step.

Comment: Thanks guys. The problem was that \tikzexternalize was in the static preamble.

Comment: @romeovs: As your comment solved the solution please add it as an answer so and0rc0r can accept it.

Comment: @Martin: Didn't to lash out at you, I just meant to say that it wasn't necessary.

Comment: @romeovs: No problem.

Answer (score 9):

Add the `\tikzexternalize` command to the *dynamic* preamble and all will be good.

So it should be:

fmt.tex - the header

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
```

test.tex - the main file

```
%&fmt
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/]
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw, circle, minimum width=1cm] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide a full example? I struggle getting it working...

Comment: Does not work for me (not even with the given example), *unless* I forget to recompile the preamble, `\tikzexternalize` is ignored and the document is built without externalization. Using MacTeX (that is TeXLive, essentially) 2016, and `-shell-escape`.

Answer (score 6):

Other answers didn't work for me and since I can't comment, this is how I did it: I added a `-fmt=yourfmtfile` option in the external/system call option. This is how my main file begins:

```
%&preamble
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/system call={xelatex -fmt=preamble.fmt \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
\tikzexternalize
```

I am using xelatex but I guess that it is the same for pdflatex as well.

Comment: Guessing can be a bit dangerous; *does* it actually work with pdflatex?  Also, it might be helpful if you explained where this should be in the questioner's files and used the MWEs he posted, so he can see exactly what you did and try it easily to see if works.

Comment: EDITED: This worked for me for pdflatex, replacing xelatex with pdflatex in the `\tikzset` argument. I also needed `\tikzexternalize` in the dynamic prelude (the rest doesn't matter), per https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16764/1340, and of course `-shell-escape` for the main document.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the tikzexternalize to be called in the static preamble (for example if you have other macros relying on that), you can do one of the following :

- name your format file after after the project jobname, either by running

  ```
  pdflatex -ini -job-name="<yourJobNameHere>" "&pdflatex fmt.tex\dump"
  ```

  or if you don't want to have to recompile the preamble each time you make a new project, by simply creating a symbolic link in your working directory, named `yourJobNameHere.fmt`, linking to the file `main.fmt`.
- add in the dynamic preamble the following command :

  ```
  \renewcommand{\tikzexternaljobname}{yourJobNameHere}
  ```

Depending on the macros you need to write in the precompiled preamble, the second solution might lead to problems, though.