# TikZ's externalization and mylatex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, format-files

I know I am greedy...

I have tried for quite a while to get TikZ's externalization facilities to work nicely with [`mylatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mylatex), without any luck.

My document currently looks like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize{filename}
\begin{document}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

I first compile it with

```
pdfetex -shell-escape --output-format pdf --jobname=filename-pdf --ini \&latex mylatex.ltx filename.tex
```

which builds a `filename-pdf.fmt` format file, which I then use

```
latex -shell-escape --output-format pdf &filename-pdf filename.tex
```

If I remove the two lines referring to externalization, this scheme works.
With them, no output is generated. (If instead of `\tikzexternalize{filename}`
I say `\tikzexternalize` the second run uses `filename-pdf` as jobname for the pdflatex runs used to compile externalized images, which does not work...)

Any ideas?

Comment: Related question: [Precompiled preamble with TikZ/Externalize](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16734/precompiled-preamble-with-tikz-externalize)

Comment: Does the `.fmt` file have to be `filename-pdf.fmt`? If I use `--jobname=filename` instead of `-jobname=filename-pdf` in the first call (and therefore `&filename` in the second, obviously), everything works fine.

Comment: @diabonas Could you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. No problem, done `:-)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here are the different jobnames of the format file and the main document. To resolve this, simply name your format file `filename.fmt` instead of `filename-pdf.fmt` and all will be fine:

#### filename.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize{filename}
\begin{document}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

Compile the format file with

```
pdfetex -shell-escape --output-format pdf --jobname=filename --ini \&latex mylatex.ltx filename.tex
```

This creates `filename.fmt`. Afterwards, run the compilation of your document with

```
latex -shell-escape --output-format pdf &filename filename.tex
```

Comment: FWIW: this point is not restricted to tikz, as mentioned within https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83486/1340.