# Comments in preamble causing errors in build with "pre-compiled" format file using mylatexformat?

Tags: compiling, preamble, format-files

Consider the following MWE - nearly the same as in [Failure with [greek] babel and lastpage, \frontmatter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228848/failure-with-greek-babel-and-lastpage-frontmatter), but not exactly - where I have a large document, for which I wanted to generate "precompiled headers" ([TikZ's externalization and mylatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19403/tikzs-externalization-and-mylatex) (note, \jobname should be the same)) and thought I'd use `mylatexformat` for it ([ultrafast pdflatex with precompiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79493/ultrafast-pdflatex-with-precompiling)).

The structure looks something like this:

> **`setup/_preamble.tex`**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{cmap}% (causes pdflatex: dangling objects discarded, no output file produced. with -ini/mylatexformat)
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[english]{babel} % ok
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel} % ok w/ hack below
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\makeatletter
\let\oldlastpage@putl@bel\lastpage@putl@bel
\renewcommand*\lastpage@putl@bel{%
  \bgroup
  \let\textlatin\@firstofone % make \textlatin a no-op
  \oldlastpage@putl@bel%
  \egroup
}
\makeatother
```

> **`test.tex`**

```
%% This is the file `test.tex'
%
\input{setup/_preamble.tex}%
%
% \csname endofdump\endcsname% may \def to \relax; https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57398
\ifcsname endofdump\endcsname%
  % it is called with precompiled header; stop here:
  \typeout{HEEEREEEE: endofdump defined!}%
  \endofdump% shouldn't be here?
  \typeout{HEEEREEEE: POST endofdump defined!}%
\else%
\fi%

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\clearpage

\section{Something}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

If I compile this with `pdflatex test.tex`, it compiles fine.

I "compile" the `test.fmt` file like this:

```
$ pdflatex -ini -jobname="test" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx "test.tex"
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (INITEX)
...
HEEEREEEE: endofdump defined!
<<ot1.cmap>><<oml.cmap>><<oms.cmap>><<omx.cmap>> ...
(\end occurred when \ifcsname on line 6 was incomplete)
Beginning to dump on file test.fmt
 (preloaded format=test 2015.2.18)
...
20 words of pdfTeX memory
...
```

... which seems to work fine.

But when I try to build the `.pdf` file using the precompiled `.fmt` file like this (I don't include the `%&test` comment as the first line of the `test.tex` file, but instead I specify it on the command line):

```
$ pdflatex --file-line-error --synctex=1 "&test" test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
...
==============================================================================
JOB NAME         : "test"
CUSTOMISED FORMAT: "test"
PRELOADED FILES:
setup/_preamble.tex
...
  t1cmtt.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
  t1cmss.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions

==============================================================================
(mylatexformat)Info: start reading document "test"
(mylatexformat)      on input line 13. (\endofdump)
==============================================================================
(./setup/_preamble.tex

./setup/_preamble.tex:1: LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 \documentclass[10pt]{
                         book}
?
```

... for some reason, *even* if the precompiled `.fmt` file is loaded, TeX *still* starts reading from `setup/_preamble.tex` - and thus reports an error of "two `\documentclass` commands"?

I already know the fix - it is to remove the comment percent characters surrounding the `\input` in `test.tex`:

```
%% This is the file `test.tex'

\input{setup/_preamble.tex}

% \csname endofdump\endcsname% may \def to \relax; https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57398
...
```

... and then running the build with the precompiled `.fmt` file (`pdflatex "&test" test.tex`) works just fine.

My question is - why should comments in the preamble have influence at all in the parsing process of `mylatexformat`?

Comment: "seems to work fine" ? rather the opposite `(\end occurred when \ifcsname on line 6 was incomplete)` is an indication that bad things happened.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle - what I meant was that the process didn't stop as on a "proper" error, and a PDF is generated, so in that regard, I consider it fine `:)` I thought I needed that `\ifcsname` in order to handle package loading after the `\endofdump`, but I probably don't need it; so that part can probably be ignored, I guess... cheers!