# Typesetting meeting minutes in MultiMarkDown and Latex (with minutes package)

Tags: sectioning

I'm trying to create a workflow where I can typeset a meeting minute using MultiMarkDown syntax and then have it converted in latex and processed to PDF.
`Minutes` is a great package to format these type of document, but it uses `\topic` `\subtopic` and `\subsubtopic` in place of `\section` `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`. While it make quite a lot of sense in a meeting minute context, it is a problem in my workflow as the MultiMarkDown processor converts headers in `\part`, `\chapter`, `\section` etc.

Can somebody give me a hint on how to redefine the `\section` command in `Minutes` in order to act as `\topic`?
As far as I can see the command definition in the package is:

```
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand*{\topic}[2][\minxx]{
\min@checktitle
%    \end{macrocode}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\immediate\gdef\thesection{\min@toptext\min@thesection}
\ifx\minxx#1\min@newcoltopic{\section}{#2}{#2}%
\else\min@newcoltopic{\section}{#1}{#2}\fi%
}
```

Unfortunately it looks like the `\topic` command definition already rely on `\section`.
Any help will be much much appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Without a MWE to test this, I would suggest you use `\let\OldSection\section`, and then define `\section` to be the same as the above defintion of `\topic`, but use `\OldSection` within this definition instead of `\section`.

Comment: Why not write the minutes in [Org-mode and export to LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54211/5701)? Writing in Org-mode is similar to writing in markdown.

Answer (score 2):

A non-Latex solution would be to write a batch/script which does the following:

1. multimarkdown->latex conversion of your document
2. replaces `\part \section \subsection` and `\subsubsection` with `Minutes` equivalents
3. runs pdflatex, etc.

The key part is the second step.

On linux you could use `sed -i 's/\\section/\\topic/g' minutes.tex` to replace all occurrences of `\section` with `\topic`. (`-i` switch makes a backup of the file and then edits the file in place. Not sure about the escaped backslashes, though.)

On Windows you could have a look at this other question:  [How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60034/791369)

**Update:** Actually, since the `\section`, etc. are generated by Multimarkdown, the best approach would be to build in support for Minutes. Have a look at the MMD Latex support files. It should be possible to modify one to work with the Minutes package. (See [line 38 of mmd-beamer-header.tex](https://github.com/fletcher/peg-multimarkdown-latex-support/blob/master/mmd-beamer-header.tex#L38) which modifies standard footnote behaviour.)

I'm not quite sure how much this works, but the author of Multimarkdown, Fletcher Penney, is usually quite helpful with questions.

Comment: I had a similar case, where I wanted `\section*` instead of `\section`.  I used sed -e 's/\\section{/\\section*/' in my make pipeline as I didn't want to accidentally double star any `\section*`s that were in my template.