# Is there some kind of LaTeX software for desktop notes?

Tags: notes

I use [atnotes](http://atnotes.free.fr/) to put sticky notes on my desktop, is there something like that with support to LaTeX?

Comment: I know. But perhaps some programmer had the same idea I had.  Also, it seems people [made some things beyond documents  with LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104248/12924).

Comment: Something like [`todonotes`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/)?

Comment: I suppose the `standalone` package could be useful for this purpose, at least in terms of creating the PDF.  Not sure how to 'stick' them to your desktop, however.  [conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/) can display things like albumart covers (i.e., graphics), so maybe that would be one option.

Comment: One option: [Everyday LaTeX and workflow?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22443/15717) with [Emacs and Org-mode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54211/15717)

Comment: @texenthusiast -- I think the OP wants LaTeX pretty-printing output for the equivalent of sticky notes you can 'stick' to your desktop (much like, as noted in the below answer, [Tomboy](http://projects.gnome.org/tomboy/index.html) --- but which does *not* give LaTeX-quality output.)

Comment: @jon yes right, somewhat off the line. There exists [LaTeX plugin for Tomboy](http://www.reitwiessner.de/programs/tomboy-latex.html), no hands on experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tomboy](http://projects.gnome.org/tomboy/index.html) is a notes manager, which has [a plugin for LaTeX formulas](http://www.reitwiessner.de/programs/tomboy-latex.html). However I'm not sure it displays notes the same way your software does.