# Is there a script converting Latex code into orgmode code?

Tags: org-mode

After various tentatives to write drafts of article directly in org-mode for Emacs, hoping to take advantage of various of its features (e.g. exporting to html, easier scope exporting than with \includeonly, automatically generating example based on inline code, etc...), I decided that I was more at ease writing my articles directly in latex (under auctex mode in Emacs).

Yet I find myself still converting large fragments of latex code to orgmode (e.g. \textemf{blabla} to /blabla/) for inclusion in org-mode documents (e.g. to export to a webpage). I do so via search and replace with regular expression, and I am thinking about  writing a general script to automatize the task, but I thought that someone else might have done so already. A quick search on Google and Stacks Exchange did not yield any useful answer.

Comment: [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) is the best way I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2):

I arrived at this page a couple of months ago, hoping for such a script.  I have written a simple search-and-replace script in Python.  It isn't very fancy, and I've only tested in on two LaTeX documents so far, but it saves me a lot of manual labour when converting from LaTeX to Orgmode.  `latex2orgmode` can be found here:

https://github.com/MarcvdSluys/Orgmode-convert

Comment: Thank you! So orgmode export no longer is a one-way-street. I'll test and give feedback.

Comment: Could you add footnotes and what about a simple translation of tabulars?

Comment: @KeksDose I was going to ask you to open an issue, but you already did.  Let's move the discussion there.

Answer (score 1):

You are right: Writing in orgmode and exporting to LaTeX may work for text, but as soon as you get into realms of more sophisticated layout, you think half of the time about how to export it properly from orgmode to LaTeX.

[Meanwhile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54205/4736) I write my drafts with orgmode. After finishing the draft, I export it to LaTeX and stick to LaTeX.

You probably won't export your whole text to a website, will you? So take the time to copy and paste a short version for the website. That saves much time in the end, compared to head scratching about export from orgmode to LaTeX for the whole document.

Comment: That's the plan, but when copy pasting short versions to the website, I find myself repeatitively translating \emph{blah} in /blah/ and \texttt{blah} in =blah= and so on. I will program a script to automatize it (and but it on github) if I don't find that someone already made one :)

Comment: @Jeremy Did you ever make such a script?

Comment: @AstroFloyd No :(

Comment: I've now written a simple Python script that does the basics.  Nothing fancy, but it saves some manual labour when converting: https://github.com/MarcvdSluys/Orgmode-convert

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/uliw/l2org enables round trip editing between latex and org mode

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.