# Extracting the structure of a LaTex document, including comments

Tags: documentation

I like to write a "special" comment with a title at the beginning of each paragraph in my documents, something like this:

```
\section{Introduction}

% 1.0 Visually tracking balls is an interesting problem.  
Text related to why tracking balls is important, blah, blah, blah.   
Blah, blah, blah. 

% 1.1 Tracking balls is difficult because of these challenges.  
Text relating the challenges, blah, blah, blah.  
More blah, blah, blah. 

% 2.0 Previous work.  
Text relating the existing work on tracking balls, blah, blah, blah.  
Blah, blah, blah.
```

This helps me keeping the content of my documents well structured.

What I'd like to do is to extract the structure of a document: sectioning commands (i.e, `\chapter`, `\section` and the like) and "special" comments at the beginning of each paragraph.
I'd like to parse a LaTex source file (or a group of them, in case the main file includes other source files) and produce a new file which contains only the sectioning commands and the "special" comments, turned into regular text (uncommented) or, better yet, turned into a bulleted list.

So the output generated running the parser on the previous code would be:

```
\section{Introduction}

\begin{itemize}  
  \item 1.0 Visually tracking balls is an interesting problem.  
  \item 1.1 Tracking balls is difficult because of these challenges.  
  \item 2.0 Previous work.  
\end{itemize}
```

The best solution I got so far consists in me labelling the special comments with a character sequence (i.e., starting them with "%$"), then grepping the occurrences of "%$" and of the sectioning commands in the source file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After a fashion, this is sort of what a `\tableofcontents` does, using information that has been written out to the .toc file.  Maybe something could be adapted along those lines.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You might need `\addcontentsline` too.

Comment: You would probably enjoy emacs’ org-mode; see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54205/org-mode-export-to-latex-temptation-or-nuisance

Comment: As far as I can see, you're not going to be able to do it easily with simple comment syntax.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is easily done with any command line tools here I use grep and sed (in cygwin bash on windows) but other systems have similar or you could use perl

If `zz.tex` is your original file,

The command line of

```bash
$ grep "\(sub\)*section\|^%" zz.tex | sed -e '/^\\s/ a \\\\begin{itemize}' -e 's/^%/\\item /' -e '$ a \\\\end{itemize}'
```

outputs

```
\section{Introduction}
\begin{itemize}
\item  1.0 Visually tracking balls is an interesting problem.  
\item  1.1 Tracking balls is difficult because of these challenges.  
\item  2.0 Previous work.  
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Sorry it took me years to mark this solution as the accepted one, I had lost track of this question.

Answer (score 10):

Here I use a "table of contents" approach, by which I mean I explicitly write information to the aux file, and process it from there.  EDITED to present two approaches: 1) where the "XYZecutive summary" is contained in the original document, and 2) where the summary is an external document.

In both cases, I have my tex file in which I can repeatedly use the macro `\addxyzline{type}{content}` to add various lines to the aux file.  I also have the `\writexyz` macro, which will read the .aux file and create an .xyz file.  It can appear in the source document after `\begin{document}`, either before any sectioning has occurred, or after all sectioning has occurred.

**APPROACH 1: XYZecutive Summary in Same Document**

In this approach, not only does the `\writexyz` macro write things to the .xyz file, it also processes that document on the second pass, formatting the contents appropriately.

The executive summary (containing all the `\addxyzline` information) appears at the invocation of `\writexyz`.  In this MWE, I place it after the toc but before the document matter.  I play with the `\addtocontents` macro definition so that the executive summary sectioning doesn't end up as duplicative sectioning in the toc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\addxyzline[2]{\addtocontents {xyz}{\protect \xyzline {#1}{#2}}}
\let\svaddtocontents\addtocontents
\makeatletter
\newcommand\writexyz{%
  \renewcommand\addtocontents[2]{\relax}%
  \clearpage\setcounter{section}{0}\noindent%
  {\Huge\hrulefill XYZecutive Summary\hrulefill\par}%
  \newcommand\xyzline[2]{\expandafter\csname##1\endcsname{##2}}\@starttoc{xyz}%
  \par\noindent\hrulefill\clearpage\setcounter{section}{0}%
  \let\addtocontents\svaddtocontents
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents% CAN UNCOMMMENT TO SEE THAT toc WORKS FINE
\writexyz

\section{Introduction}
\addxyzline{section}{Introduction}

\addxyzline{begin}{itemize}
\addxyzline{item}{1.0 Visually tracking balls is an interesting problem.}
Text related to why tracking balls is important, blah, blah, blah.   
Blah, blah, blah. 

\addxyzline{item}{1.1 Tracking balls is difficult because of these challenges.}
Text relating the challenges, blah, blah, blah.  
More blah, blah, blah. 

\addxyzline{item}{2.0 Previous work.}
Text relating the existing work on tracking balls, blah, blah, blah.  
Blah, blah, blah.
\addxyzline{end}{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**APPROACH 2: Separate Summary Document**

Here, I create my document body as before, but the `\writexyz` will not write the summary to the same document, but merely to the .xyz file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\addxyzline[2]{\addtocontents {xyz}{\protect \xyzline {#1}{#2}}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\writexyz{\newcommand\xyzline[2]{}\@starttoc{xyz}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
%\tableofcontents% CAN UNCOMMMENT TO SEE THAT toc WORKS FINE
\section{Introduction}
\addxyzline{section}{Introduction}

\addxyzline{begin}{itemize}
\addxyzline{item}{1.0 Visually tracking balls is an interesting problem.}
Text related to why tracking balls is important, blah, blah, blah.   
Blah, blah, blah. 

\addxyzline{item}{1.1 Tracking balls is difficult because of these challenges.}
Text relating the challenges, blah, blah, blah.  
More blah, blah, blah. 

\addxyzline{item}{2.0 Previous work.}
Text relating the existing work on tracking balls, blah, blah, blah.  
Blah, blah, blah.
\addxyzline{end}{itemize}

\writexyz
\end{document}
```

As far as screen output, the compilation produces the output of the original document, without regard to the `\addxyzline` content:

[image]

However, it also creates a .xyz file (in this case xyz.xyz, since I had called my original file xyz.tex), with the following information:

```
\xyzline {section}{Introduction}
\xyzline {begin}{itemize}
\xyzline {item}{1.0 Visually tracking balls is an interesting problem.}
\xyzline {item}{1.1 Tracking balls is difficult because of these challenges.}
\xyzline {item}{2.0 Previous work.}
\xyzline {end}{itemize}
```

containing all of my `\addxyzline` information.

Then, I have a very simple second tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\xyzline[2]{\csname#1\endcsname {#2}\par}
\begin{document}
\input{xyz.xyz}% NAME OF .xyz FILE GOES HERE IN THE ARGUMENT
\end{document}
```

which provides the xyz summary info

[image]

---

**POSTSCRIPT**

As one can see, the first argument of `\addxyzline` is the text of any macro name.  In my MWE, I have used "section", "begin", "item", and "end".  Other useful incantations might include

```
\addxyzline{relax}{this is just text added on the same line}
\addxyzline{newline}{this is just text on a new line}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a ConTeXt solution that uses the "table of content" approach. Pick a section head that you are not using, say `subsubject` and use that to annotate your *outline* in the main document:

```
\setuphead[subsubject][placehead=empty, before=,after=, incrementnumber=yes]

\starttext

\section{Introduction}

\subsubject{1.0 Visually tracking balls is an interesting problem.}
Text related to why tracking balls is important, blah, blah, blah.   
Blah, blah, blah. 

\subsubject{1.1 Tracking balls is difficult because of these challenges.}
Text relating the challenges, blah, blah, blah.  
More blah, blah, blah. 

\subsubject{2.0 Previous work. }
Text relating the existing work on tracking balls, blah, blah, blah.  
Blah, blah, blah. 

\stoptext
```

In the first line, `placehead=empty` tells ConTeXt not to place the head (subsubject, in this case) in the output; `incrementnumber=yes` is need to ensure that the ToC entry is written in a way that is accessible through other files.

Next create a separate file to create an outline. I'll assume that the name of the main file was `test.tex`.

```
\starttext
\ctxlua{job.load("test.tuc")}
\placelist[section,subsubject]
          [pagenumber=no, headnumber=no]   
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]