# What are the best practices for indentation in a TeX file?

Tags: best-practices, sourcecode

In the text editor that I'm using (Atom), it automatically indents when I use `\begin{...}`. In some cases, it seems to increase the readability of the document, but otherwise seems unnecessary. Is it better to indent or not indent in a TeX file?

Comment: really it's a matter of personal style, but don't fight your editor, if your editor wants to format/indent the file, either accept that or change the  layout options in the editor, if you manually have to keep re-correcting indentation as you and the editor disagree on good style, then it just causes pain.

Comment: possibly a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65997/is-there-a-default-official-standard-vim-indentation-file-for-tex-or-just-b?rq=1 (even though the title mentions vim, neither question nor answer are vim specific)

Comment: Personally I find that often distract more that it help, specially if this cause a line too long, so you lost the end in the right border or you get a soft line break if wrapping is activated. Anyway, the result is the same, so ...   is better as you want.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But small disagreements are tolerable, if you like the editor otherwise and can't find a better one ;). Mine wants to indent everything in the `document` environment, which I don't like. But you only have to correct the first line. So that's annoying but manageable. (Not its most annoying feature, anyway.)

Comment: It makes it easier to find errors. For me, anyway, if environments are indented as they nest. You've got a visual representation of the nesting.