# Should I use a space or a new line after a period?

Tags: spacing, best-practices, sourcecode

After a period in a .tex file, within a paragraph, should I use a space or a new line?

I.e. like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec rhoncus vestibulum metus ut suscipit. Sed suscipit sem ligula, iaculis dignissim turpis ultricies vitae. Curabitur interdum lorem fermentum tellus blandit venenatis et et nisi. Ut elementum interdum nulla, at dapibus urna consequat ut. Nulla sodales in nulla et semper. Proin et consequat lacus. Nam faucibus, dui sit amet sodales cursus, nunc neque mattis eros, a pharetra purus elit quis tortor.
```

Or like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Donec rhoncus vestibulum metus ut suscipit.
Sed suscipit sem ligula, iaculis dignissim turpis ultricies vitae.
Curabitur interdum lorem fermentum tellus blandit venenatis et et nisi.
Ut elementum interdum nulla, at dapibus urna consequat ut.
Nulla sodales in nulla et semper.
Proin et consequat lacus.
Nam faucibus, dui sit amet sodales cursus, nunc neque mattis eros, a pharetra purus elit quis tortor.
```

Comment: It makes no difference, as long as you don't use a _blank_ line (ie two newlines) any number of spaces or a single blank line are treated the same way.

Comment: Ok:-) But if you are asking about editor preferences rather than TeX behaviour, you could perhaps make that clearer in your question, As that is not at all clear as it is currently worded.

Comment: I recommend you read the answers at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62446/86

Comment: https://www.xkcd.com/1285/ Obviously (^;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It’s up to you, both a space or a new line work fine and result in the same output. I recommend using a new line:

- If your pdf viewer and your editor support SyncTeX, you can click a word in the pdf and you will be taken to the corresponding line in your source.
- It’ll be easier to find LaTeX errors if your lines are shorter. (Usually error messages tell you in which line the error occurred.)
- You’ll notice if one single sentence gets too long just by looking at the lines. (I recommend setting up your editor to soft-wrap your lines after a certain number of characters, e.g. 80.)

The setup I’m mentioning here works great with TeXstudio and SumatraPDF.

Comment: I use MACpreview and MacVim so I cannot add the soft-wrap but you explanation makes sense about the new lines

EDIT:
Turns out I can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/989093/soft-wrap-at-80-characters-in-vim-in-window-of-arbitrary-width

Answer (score 7):

There is no global recommendation. It really depends on your preferences, the tool you use, and your editing context.

For instance, if several persons edit a tex file using SVN, you should use new lines to form a paragraph. In this case SVN will make a diff line by line instead paragraph by paragraph avoiding many conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers so far (with which I personally agree):

If your editor window is usually small (e.g., because the remainder of the monitor space is usually occupied by something more important than the LaTeX editor or because your screen is simply very small), separate the sentences by blanks. With each sentence of a paragraph started on a new line, you sometimes simply waste extremely valuable screen space.