# How can numbering of specific headings be disabled in Org-mode's LaTeX export?

Tags: sectioning, emacs, org-mode

By default Org-mode exports to numbered LaTeX headings. For example, the following

```
#+title: Test

* Introduction
* Heading
* Heading
* References
```

exports to

```latex
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec-1}
\section{Heading}
\label{sec-2}
\section{Heading}
\label{sec-3}
\section{References}
\label{sec-4}
```

It is possible to disable numbering for *all* LaTeX headings by adding `#+options: num:nil` as in

```
#+title: Test
#+options: num:nil

* Introduction
* Heading
* Heading
* References
```

which exports to

```latex
\section*{Introduction}
\label{sec-1}
\section*{Heading}
\label{sec-2}
\section*{Heading}
\label{sec-3}
\section*{References}
\label{sec-4}
```

Note that `\section*` is a LaTeX macro for unnumbered section.

Is it possible to tell Org-mode to *not* number *particular* headings, i.e. via editing the [properties](http://orgmode.org/guide/Properties.html#Properties) of headings? For example, is it possible to get the following LaTeX exported from Org-mode:

```latex
\section*{Introduction}
\label{sec-1}
\section{Heading}
\label{sec-2}
\section{Heading}
\label{sec-3}
\section*{References}
\label{sec-4}
```

I am running Org-mode 7.6 in Emacs 23.3.1.

Comment: It is a common misperception that all and everything you can do with LaTeX should be possible by using Org-mode and exporting to LaTeX. No! Write your document in LaTeX and link into it from your Org-mode file.

Comment: @KeksDose I do not expect to do everything in Org-mode that I can do with LaTeX. I do however expect to do some basic and useful things in Org-mode that are also possible with LaTeX. This issue is one of them and it is something that can be handy also when exporting from Org-mode to other formats such as html. Also, I do not think it is effective to write directly in LaTeX. I prefer [to draft in Org-mode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22443/5701).

Comment: There are gazillions of things which are considered as basic and usefull, depends on whom you ask. Go and draft your document in Org-mode, I admit to do so as well, but in LaTeX you will have to give some finishing touches to the *.tex-file. I'm impressed about the features of Org-mode as well, it even can calculate (have you noticed the `radiotables`? Incredible!), but what you and many other people ask, seems the direct highway to hell for Org-mode. Besides that: All those features would destroy the clean outline of Org-mode files.

Comment: @KeksDose As said, controlling heading numbering for particular headers is useful not only for LaTeX. Also, it would *not* interfere with the clean outline of Org file because it can be implemented via [properties](http://orgmode.org/guide/Properties.html#Properties) which *are already* in Org-mode. Org-mode already does something similar with properties to [handle beamer export](http://orgmode.org/manual/Beamer-class-export.html#Beamer-class-export).

Comment: I searched through stackoverflow and found some of your questions related to exporting. Would you mind to give a résumé on all your specific solutions you found? Maybe you can share a link here at tex.stackexchange. Probably many people would find that usefull!

Comment: @KeksDose I am not sure how you mean for me to share it. Maybe we could continue the discussion [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends)? Just `@` me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3306/discussion-between-keks-dose-and-n-n)

Comment: It would be helpful toward a real answer to find the data property that is set/unset with `num:nil` and then set it locally whenever a an appropriate `:NUM:` (or whatever) property is found.

Answer (score 32):

You need `org-mode` 8.3 to do this.

From ORG-NEWS

```
* Version 8.3
[...]
** New features
[...]
*** Export unnumbered headlines
Headlines, for which the property ~UNNUMBERED~ is non-nil, are now
exported without section numbers irrespective of their levels.  The
property is inherited by children.
```

For example

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (require 'ox-latex)
  (insert "
* numbered
** subnumbered
* unnumbered
:PROPERTIES:
:UNNUMBERED: t
:END:
** also unnumbered
")
  (org-latex-export-as-latex nil nil nil t))
```

produces

```
\section{numbered}
\label{sec-1}
\subsection{subnumbered}
\label{sec-1-1}
\section*{unnumbered}
\label{unnumbered-1}
\subsection*{also unnumbered}
\label{unnumbered-2}
```

Edit: Since I wrote this the naming scheme of labels changed, so labels would look different these days.

Edit2: One can set headline properties easily with `C-c C-x p`.

Answer (score 13):

**Note**: This answer is now outdated; see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224259/117649).

---

Selective numbering is not supported at the moment (even in Org-mode
master). However you can choose to not number headings beyond a certain
depth by specifying something like this:

```
#+OPTIONS: H:3 num:2

* Introduction

* Heading
** Something 1
*** Something 2

* Heading
** Something 1
*** Something 2

* References
```

The above will export up to 3 levels of headlines but will number only
up to level 2.

```
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec-1}

\section{Heading}
\label{sec-2}
\subsection{Something 1}
\label{sec-2-1}
\subsubsection*{Something 2}
\label{sec-2-1-1}

\section{Heading}
\label{sec-3}
\subsection{Something 1}
\label{sec-3-1}
\subsubsection*{Something 2}
\label{sec-3-1-1}
\section{References}
\label{sec-4}
```

PS: I don't see how this is more appropriate in tex rather than stackoverflow.

Comment: Indeed, this is not exactly what I want. I want to be able to have numbered and unnumbered headings of the same level. Strange way of supporting numbering depth. A more elegant solution for Org-mode would be to add `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}` to the preamble when `#+OPTIONS: H:3 num:2` rather than adding `\section*`s. I have flagged for migration back to SO. Do not understand why it got migrated here in the first place.

Comment: @N.N. I think it's done this way because Org-mode tries to be export backend agnostic. So every time you enter a latex snippet, the disparity between exported files with different backends increase. That said, I believe it could be more configurable after the new export engine is in place.

Answer (score 6):

I think there is still not an option in org-mode. One work around I used recently to use `ignoreheading` for required node and give latex command explicitly for unnumbered section.

```
* Abstract                                                   :ignoreheading:
\section*{Abstract}
blah
```

ofcourse you should have a filter defined in your `init.el` for `ignoreheading` to work.

```
;;; Nicolas Goaziou, http://article.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/67692
(defun org-latex-ignore-heading-filter-headline (headline backend info)
  "Strip headline from HEADLINE. Ignore BACKEND and INFO."
  (when (and (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'latex)
             (string-match "\\`.*ignoreheading.*\n" headline))
    (replace-match "" nil nil headline)))
(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-headline-functions
             'org-latex-ignore-heading-filter-headline)
```