# Suppressing the final section of an org-mode beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, org-mode

My org-mode beamer organization is something like:

```
* Introduction

* Presentation

** Section 1
** Section 2

* Thanks
- email
- contact, etc..
```

I'd like to suppress the `thanks` page on my TOC.  How can I specifically omit a section heading from the TOC?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Since you define [this in the preamble from the tutorial](https://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/beamer/tutorial.html):

```
#+OPTIONS:   TeX:t LaTeX:t skip:nil d:nil todo:t pri:nil tags:not-in-toc
```

You can use the tag :not-in-toc:

```
* Thanks
  :PROPERTIES: 
  :not-in-toc:
  :BEAMER_env: frame
  :END:
- email
- contact, etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

```
 * My Good Title
:PROPERTIES:
:UNNUMBERED: t
:END:
```

From:

- https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32926/unnumbered-section-among-numbered-ones-in-org-mode
- [How can numbering of specific headings be disabled in Org-mode's LaTeX export?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52460/how-can-numbering-of-specific-headings-be-disabled-in-org-modes-latex-export/127287#127287)
- https://orgmode.org/manual/Drawers.html