# How to make LuaLateX faster?

Tags: luatex, compiling, performance

There have been several ideas to improve the speed of PDFLaTeX.

- [Script to automate externalizing TikZ graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1460/script-to-automate-externalizing-tikz-graphics)
- [Ultrafast PDFLaTeX with precompiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79493/ultrafast-pdflatex-with-precompiling)
- and many more...

Which additional tricks improve the speed of LuaLaTeX?

Comment: I suspect that the question is too broad to answer. Most of the things that apply to pdftex such as making formats apply also to luatex. additional lua-specific things hard to say, you can try byte compiling lua but unless you have an awful lot of lua possibly doesn't make much difference.

Comment: In the case of ConTeXt (which is about 50 % pure Lua) you can gain some speed by using LuaJITTeX, which uses LuaJIT instead of the normal Lua interpreter.  Surprisingly, you can kill that speedup immediately by actually turning on the JIT.  So use `context --jit` but not `context --jiton`.