# What was the right way to draw this image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams

I appreciate the fact that LaTeX is WYSIWYW but overtime I am questioning myself wether the idea of WYSIWYW for pure graphics is still reasonable. Today it took me more than one hour to realize the following picture with the following code (and two others which are very similar to this).

On my Lenovo ThinkPad L530 (Ubuntu and Openbox) it takes more than 15 seconds to compile each time and reducing the samples from 2000 to 500 it still takes more than 3 seconds with a much worse result. I am still not satisfied of this image beacuse of the sharpness of the intersections of the parabola with the horizontal and vertical lines. So here are my questions:

1. What was the right code I should have used to make a fast compiling and good looking picture?
2. How long does it normally take you to come out with the right code for such an image?
3. Which WYSIWYG alternatives to tikz you would recommend for this kind of pictures?

Thank you for your patience.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
axis line style=->,
xmin=-.4,xmax=1.4,
ymin=-.4,ymax=2.4,
x=3cm,
y=3cm,
xlabel=$p$,
ylabel=$s$,
]

\addplot[name path=A,black,restrict x to domain=-0.001:0.359, samples= 2000] {2};
\addplot[name path=B,black,restrict x to domain=-0.001:0.359, samples= 2000] {1+0.5*x};
\addplot[gray!40] fill between[of=A and B];
\addplot[name path=C,black,restrict x to domain=0.349:1.001, samples= 2000] {2};
\addplot[name path=D,black,restrict x to domain=0.349:1.001, samples= 2000] {2*sqrt(x)};
\addplot[gray!40] fill between[of=C and D];

\addplot[restrict x to domain=-0.001:1.001, samples= 2000, smooth,line width=0.35mm, -]{2*sqrt(x)};
\addplot[restrict y to domain=-0.001:2.001, samples= 2000, smooth,line width=0.35mm, -]({0},{x});
\addplot[restrict x to domain=-0.001:1.001, samples= 2000, smooth,line width=0.35mm, -]{2};
\addplot[restrict x to domain=-0.301:1.301, samples= 2000, smooth,line width=0.15mm, -]{1+0.5*x};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: my very old pc (8+ years, first generation of pentium, but 8GB ram and ssd) need less the 1 second to compile your mwe. :-)

Comment: sorry, my pc need  15 second ... however, your code can be simplified. see answer below.

Comment: You could externalize the `tikzpicture`. That way it is only recreated if you change something. (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1475/36296)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
axis line style=->,
xmin=-.4,xmax=1.4,
ymin=-.4,ymax=2.4,
x=3cm,
y=3cm,
xlabel=$p$,
ylabel=$s$,
samples=100% <--- moved here
]

\addplot[name path=A,domain=0:0.36] {2};
\addplot[name path=B,domain=0:0.36] {1+0.5*x};
\addplot[gray!40] fill between[of=A and B];
%
\addplot[name path=C,domain=0.35:1] {2};
\addplot[name path=D,domain=0.35:1] {2*sqrt(x)};
\addplot[gray!40] fill between[of=C and D];

\addplot[domain=0:1, line width=0.35mm]{2*sqrt(x)};
\addplot[domain=0:2, line width=0.35mm]({0},{x});
\addplot[domain=0:1, line width=0.35mm]{2};
\addplot[domain=-0.3:1.3, line width=0.15mm]{1+0.5*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

i made the following changes:

- reduce number of samples to 100 and move declaration to `axis` options (for reason of shorter code)
- remove `smooth` options
- replaced `restrict x to domain` with`domain`
- rounded limits of domain (from `-0.001` to `0`, etc)

after this changes the computation time on my old pc was reduced about 4 seconds and resulted images (to my taste) looks better :-)

**addendum:**
as pointed [Sergei Golovan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121550/sergei-golovan) in his comment below, for drawing function square root function on domain `0:1` is sensible to draw it as inverse function in the parametric form.

Since the square root function have infinite derivative around zero, it's hard to draw it nice, i.e. you need many sample points. Derivative of the inverse function in origin is zero, therefore it can be drawn with few samples. for example, with only 25 samples result with use of inverse function is visible almost the same as with use of direct function at 200 samples.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
axis line style=->,
xmin=-.4,xmax=1.4,
ymin=-.4,ymax=2.4,
x=3cm,
y=3cm,
xlabel=$p$,
ylabel=$s$,
samples=20
]

\addplot[name path=A,domain=0:0.36] {2};
\addplot[name path=B,domain=0:0.36] {1+0.5*x};
\addplot[gray!40] fill between[of=A and B];
%
\addplot[name path=C,domain=0.35:1] {2};
\addplot[name path=D,domain=0.35:1] {2*sqrt(x)};
\addplot[gray!40] fill between[of=C and D];

% parametric form of inverse function
\addplot[domain=0:2, line width=0.35mm] ({x*x/4},  % <-- x values
                                         {x}       % <-- y values
                                         );
\addplot[domain=0:1, line width=0.35mm]{2};
\addplot[domain=-0.3:1.3, line width=0.15mm]{1+0.5*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd also replace `\addplot[domain=0:1, line width=0.35mm]{2*sqrt(x)};` by the parametrized `\addplot[domain=0:2, line width=0.35mm]({x*x/4},{x});` to avoid a kink near zero.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan, please be so kind and give me a tip, where (if it is) described parametric way of function's calculation ?

Comment: I can find many examples of parametric plots in the pgfplots documentation (http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf). Though if you ask how the new parametrization was chosen, I just used an inverse function. Since the square root function have infinite derivative around zero, it's hard to make its plot nice (you need many sample points). The inverse function doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 4):

For fun, a `pstricks` version:

```
\documentclass[x11names, svgnames, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} %% for pdflatex compilation

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=2cm, algebraic, plotstyle=curve, plotpoints=500,arrowinset=0.125, arrowsize=3pt, linejoin=1,labelsep = 8pt}

\begin{pspicture*}(-0.4,-0.3)(1.6,2.5)
    \psaxes[linecolor=LightSteelBlue3, ticksize =-3pt 3pt, tickcolor=LightSteelBlue3, arrows=->, subticksize =1, subtickcolor=LightSteelBlue3, subtickwidth=0.4pt, subticks=2, Dx=1, Dy=1](0,0)(-0.4,- 0.3)(1.5, 2.5) [$p$,120] [$s$,-30]
    \uput[d](0.5,0){0.5} \uput[l](0,0.5){0.5}\uput[l](0,1.5){1.5}
    \psplot{0}{1}{2*sqrt(x)}
    \psplot[linewidth=0.5pt]{-0.4}{1.5}{1 + x/2}
    \pscustom[linecolor=SteelBlue, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=Gainsboro!80!Lavender]{\psline(0,1)(0,2)(1,2)\psplot{1}{0.343}{2*sqrt(x)}\closepath}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for enthusiasm for `pstricks`. ones i try to learn it, but i give up and now stick only with `tikz` :-)

Comment: I think `pstricks` is much easier to learn than `tikz` (latex syntax!), and often less verbose. But tikz has nevertheless very interesting features.