# Speeding up LaTeX compilation

Tags: compiling, performance

Usually I don't mind about LaTeX's compilation speed, because a paper of less than 20 pages is compiled rather fast.  However, I am working on a large document - A report with more than 80 pages.  Compilation times are starting to slow me down.  I saw the couple of answers here on this topic, but most of my graphics are external and I don't use Tikz.  As a matter of fact, I'm not sure what's slowing the compilation down, other than the amount of text and required layout.

1. What's your best speeding-tex-up trick, other than externalizing graphics and pre-compiling the preamble?
2. How can I know what's slowing TeX down?

Comment: Forgive me if I'm totally of-base, but isn't this a community-wiki type of question? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Related: [Tips for choosing hardware for best latex compile performance](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103565/tips-for-choosing-hardware-for-best-latex-compile-performance)

Comment: Could someone clarify what is meant by 'externalizing graphics' and 'pre-compiling the preamble'? Perhaps as an answer below...

Comment: @dardisco "externalize graphics": tell TikZ to write any graphics into an external file, so that subsequent compilations can simply include the file (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/477859/107497).  "pre-compile the preamble": dump TeX's preamble to `file.fmt`, so that subsequent compilations can quickly read in that file and start from there instead of going through all of the `newdefs` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79493/107497 and many links therein).

Comment: Related (speed up pandoc compilation): [latex - Simple and fast PDF compilation with Pandoc - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395718/simple-and-fast-pdf-compilation-with-pandoc)

Comment: Related: if someone is using MikTeX, there are claims that it's slower than TeXlive https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20037/250119

Comment: I agree with you. Latex is slow for large documents. It takes me now close to 12 hrs to compile my pdf file using lualatex. The file is a little large (106,500 pages) but still, I have lots of RAM and very fast PC. It should not be this slow in the year 2023. May be in 1980,  but not today.

Comment: @Nasser Wow. Out of curiosity, which kind of documents might have 106500 pages? (Putting together the collective works of the productive mathematicians like Euler, Erdős, and Grothendieck would be an overwhelming task for a human, so the only thing that comes to my mind is a large computer-generated mathematical proof or a complete printout of a human DNA.)

Comment: @AlMa0  It is a program I wrote which solves differential equations from textbooks automatically showing step-by-step solutions. It has now over 10,000 problems and each can  have many steps. The program generates Latex and then I compile it to PDF and HTML (using tex4ht). Current version is [here](https://12000.org/my_notes/solving_ODE/current_version/index.htm) I bought a new PC with lots of RAM hoping lualatex will be faster but that did not help. It is just slow to compile large files.

Comment: The [`memoize`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoize) package is good for externalizing graphics

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Beware of Greeks bearing gifts... Apparently, the nice `todonotes` package that I used dragged Tikz along with it, and introduced a **major** slowdown.  Switching to simple marginpars gave a nice speedup.  It should be noted that this package is a performance Trojan horse.

Comment: +1 for the info about "todo". However, it would be best if you don't ask questions in your answers, so please remove the last sentence (and edit your question if you want to).

Comment: @Little Bobby Tables, @Hendrik: Except that the information is incorrect: the `todo` package does *not* load `tikz`, although the `todonotes` package does.  Please be careful when referring to packages by name, especially when the information is negative.

Comment: @Alan: Oops, thanks a lot for the correction. (Incidentally, only the first "@" in a comment notifies a user. So in your case, "@Hendrik, @Little Bobby Tables" would have been the better order; this would have notified both of us since the author of the answer gets notified anyway.)

Comment: @Hendrik Thanks. How the whole "@" thing works is a bit mysterious anyway.  Do I have to use the full name or will this get to you with just "@Hendrik"?

Comment: @All: Oops, my bad - I hurried a bit when writing the answer.  Of course it is todonotes - The whole problem is with the Tikz routine that paints the nice notes.

Comment: @Alan: I've asked this on meta some time ago; there you can find the [full explanation](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598/when-writing-a-comment-how-do-i-ensure-that-the-person-it-is-addressed-to-gets-n/599#599).

Comment: What do you mean by "nice speedup"? My compilation got faster in the 10% range. Not bad but also not really life changing :/

Comment: Man, I wish latexmk had an option for this.

Comment: If you precompile your headers then the fact that tikz is loaded should not impact much on compilation speed.  It's good practice in any event.

Comment: Thank you! This reduced the compilation time for my document from 7s to about 2s.

Comment: Related: how to benchmark which package takes how long [profiling - Package loading speeds - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141661/package-loading-speeds/639016#639016)

Answer (score 79):

large documents start with pages >500 ...
Create a script which runs:

```
pdflatex -draftmode file
bibtex file # or biber
makeindex file.idx # if needed
makeindex -s style.gls ...# for glossary if needed
pdflatex -draftmode file
pdflatex file
```

The compilation can now be speedup if you run `bibtex/makeindex/...` only when there were changes in this area. Can be detected with a `diff` for the auxiliary files.

Comment: Couldn't the second `pdflatex` run also use `-draftmode`?

Comment: @Philipp: yes, we can ... :-)

Comment: Even better would be creating a Makefile. That way you can detect if eg makeindex has to be run. eg http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/pub/publishing/latex/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/ionumbers/Makefile

Comment: you can it detect only for special cases, because I can define my own file extension and then _yor_ Makefile cannot detect _my_ use of `makeindex` or `xindy` or `splitindex` ...

Comment: Please let me know the same approach for `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`.

Comment: Just information: `-draftmode` can be used only for `pdflatex` and `latex`. `xelatex` has no such an option.

Comment: If you need only one latex run this approach will slow down the compilation!

Comment: That's obvious ...

Comment: Making this work in TexStudio: Go to `Settings > User Commands`, add `pdflatex -draftmode %.tex |
biber % --output-safechars | pdflatex -draftmode %.tex | pdflatex -synctex=1 %.tex | txs:///view`

Comment: Even I make changes on the latex file it says: `pdfTeX warning: \pdfdraftmode enabled, not changing output pdf` after running `pdflatex -draftmode file`

Answer (score 56):

I think the most effective way to save time is to avoid compiling the document time and time again. Compilations are often not really needed, when we change several words or a simple equation.

For large documents, we can split them into small pieces using `\include` command. Then `\includeonly` helps us to compile the only piece we are interested in, leaving the whole compilation to the last stage.

For complex tables or graphs made by TeX, put them into seperate TeX files first to verify the code, then add them to the document.

Sometimes compilation options may affect the speed. `pdflatex -interaction=batchmode foo` is often faster than `pdflatex foo`, this avoid scrolling informations. There may be more, say, `xelatex -no-pdf foo` is faster than `xelatex foo`, if it isn't the last round.

Comment: Which one will run faster, with `batchmode` or `nonstopmode`?

Comment: @DamienWalters: `batchmode` is faster.

Comment: related: http://hilbertastronaut.blogspot.com/2008/12/making-latex-builds-faster.html

Comment: I disagree with the first part of that advice. Frequent compilation is very much needed when working with Tex, mainly due to the possibility of introducing a syntax error/typo etc when writing which will be almost impossible to find, as the common ones result in non-local errors. Another reason is that the advice is irrelevant, as mostly frequent compilations will not be due to added text, but things like tweaking the bibliography, which requires dozens of lengthy compilations runs and can, therefore, take hours.

Comment: For `\includeonly`, an alternative is to use `standalone` package and compile the individual part instead of the whole document – the advantage is that you can use `\input` and don't have to break each section into a separate page.

Answer (score 48):

If you are using `XeLaTeX`, a substantial amount of time is spent gzipping data with highest compression (**9**) in the `xdvipdfmx` command.

```
~$ xdvipdfmx --help
…
-z number   Set zlib compression level (0-9) [9]
…
```

For me, on a 90 page document:

```
~$ time xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode Thesis.tex
…
real    0m6.056s
~$ ls -lh Thesis.pdf 
… 6,0M … Thesis.pdf
```

Without compression:

```
~$ time xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode -output-driver='xdvipdfmx -z0' Thesis.tex
…
real    0m2.417s
~$ ls -lh Thesis.pdf 
… 142M … Thesis.pdf
```

That is **~60% time saved** but **23× bigger**. Ok, some compression is clearly needed. My sweet spot:

```
~$ time xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode -output-driver='xdvipdfmx -z3' Thesis.tex
…
real    0m2.957s
~$ ls -lh Thesis.pdf 
… 6,9M … Thesis.pdf
```

That is 0.5s for compression or some 16% of the total time, as opposed to the majority of the time with default settings. I can usually live well with the 15% bigger file size.
Of course, it does make sense to use **-z9** for the **final** build.

I did not use `XeTeX` but assume the same scenario applies.

Comment: I am adding ``-file-line-error -synctex=1 `` to your suggestions above, like this:
``xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -synctex=1 -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -z0" "$1"``, which is allowing me to have the speed gain while retaining ``synctex`` advantages 
(NB: the syntax I have here with ``"$1"`` is TeXShop's)

Comment: Note that ``xdvipdfmx -z9`` is **faster and** results in a **smaller file** than using ``xdvipdfmx -z0`` together with ``optpdf``. To increase the speed even more I also use ``xelatex -interaction=batchmode -draftmode -no-pdf`` for the first time(s) and then ``xdvipdfmx -z9`` to convert the xdy to pdf. (n × ``xelatex -no-pdf`` + ``xdvipdfmx`` vs. (n - 1) × ``xelatex -no-pdf`` + ``xelatex`` does not really make a difference in my example)

Comment: There are also other ways to change the compression level, see [xetex - prevent xelatex from compressing the output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/483038/250119) and tex.stackexchange.com/a/53252/250119  and [luatex - LuaLaTeX: How to speed up PDF generation? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/581836/lualatex-how-to-speed-up-pdf-generation)

Comment: `latexmk -xelatex` handles all the advice in this answer and comments to this answer: it compiles with `-no-pdf` by default, then once finished with the `.xdv` it then runs `xdvipdfmx`. 

Answer (score 36):

The most useful trick I know is: do not do textual changes and layout changes at the same time, but make a clear division between them.

I first fix up all the text issues (there is hardly any need to recompile during that cycle) and only afterwards worry about layout and page breaks. The separation means that in the second cycle, I can usually tackle more than one display problem simultaneously.

The second most useful trick I know is: buy a computer with a faster CPU.

Precompilation of the header will only save you some startup time, but does nothing for consecutive pages, so the effect diminishes as your document grows.

Comment: I agree on the separation between typing text with rare compilations, and then doing the layout several bits at a time. When I remember to apply it, it frees my mind a lot from all the thoughts about layout.

Comment: Note, that adding more RAM will normally not increase TeX's speed. I just tested a not-too-small document with many packages and had a 49 MB RAM usage of the pdflatex process (peak value) plus 47 MB file cache usage after the compilation process (I dropped the caches before the measurements). So 100 MB of free memory when the OS and all the other applications are loaded seems to be enough for most cases. The only thing that does matter is the single-core (integer) cpu speed.

Comment: The RAM hint is more than misleading and should be removed! `pdflatex` is a CPU–bound process. See [Tips for choosing hardware for best latex compile performance](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103565/tips-for-choosing-hardware-for-best-latex-compile-performance)

Comment: is it possible to compile latex using GPU?

Comment: @alper See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409232/is-it-possible-to-use-gpu-acceleration-on-compiling-large-latex-documents.

Answer (score 28):

Although the original post is rather old, I just stumbled upon this issue myself with a 100+ pages project with lots of figures.

If you're still working on the document and the resulting PDF file size is less important, you may try adding the following primitives at the beginning of your document

```
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0
```

This significantly increased the PDF file size for me, but in turn reduced compilation time to (not by) about 34%. If you're done editing and want to compile the final version, just comment out these lines.

This is somehwat related to *I have a name now*'s [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263695/171933), but doesn't require the command line and appears to be independent of whether you're using pdflatex or other engines.

Best,
r.

Comment: I think this one is dependent on PDF? I also left a comment under that post for method in other engines, one of them (claims to be) engine independent. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8791/speeding-up-latex-compilation/263695#comment1554174_263695

Comment: I tried this on a 450-page document, and made absolutely no difference. It is not figure-heavy, but uses tcolorbox in almost every page.

Comment: This reduces my compilation time from 10 seconds to to 1.5 seconds, albeit with a file size increase of 33 times. But still a very good timesaver!

Comment: **Note**: On LuaTeX use `\pdfvariable compresslevel=0 \pdfvariable objcompresslevel=0` instead, or add `\usepackage{luatex85}` before it. Refer to `texdoc luatex` for more details.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a tip:

Beamer+graphics is a time-consuming combination that I revisit every now and then when preparing presentations. What I do is keep all my graphics in a directory `images` that is actually a symbolic link to either `images-hires` or `images-lowres`. The latter is a script-generated directory with a copy of each image in `image-hires` but with a considerable resize transformation.

This process could be even smarter with a small preamble that checks the `draft` option of the document class and sets the correct path with `\graphicspath`. But I haven't done it because I didn't know this macro before and I am not very skilled at LaTeX/TeX macros and magics.

Comment: With `pdflatex -draftmode file` the images are not read which is useful until the very last pdflatex run.

Comment: @Herbert: Is there a difference between passing `-draftmode` to `pdflatex` used to compile an input file without `draft` option passed to `\documentclass` and passing `draft` to `\documentclass` compiled with  `pdflatex` invoked without `-draftmode` option?

Comment: the `draft` option is far different from using the option `-draftmode`. The latter didn't produce a pdf file!

Comment: Using imagemagick's convert program in a script with the [-density](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7584726/3096687) and [-quality](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality) option set to a low value is probably an easy, cross-platform, and free way to do this.

Comment: Specifically, I use `$ convert figure.png -resize 20% ./preview/figure.png`.

Answer (score 15):

When you need to iterate on something (say, the formatting of an equation), a quick and dirty but very effective trick is to comment out the bulk of the document using:

`\iffalse`

all the stuff you don't need to compile every time...

`\fi`

then you can focus in on the particular section you are working on, until you've got it just right with a tight edit/compile loop.

Then uncomment the rest of the document.

Comment: Super helpful for debugging also. For us beginners, could you perhaps expand a little on what's happening here/ how this works?

Comment: `\iffalse ... \fi` evaluates the code in `...` if False evaluates to `True` (like `if (false) { ... }` in C-like languages), so it effectively "deactivates" the code contained inside and prevents TeX from compiling it.

Comment: For quick formatting of a smallish amount of source, in TeXShop you may use the Experiment menu command, which just compiles the text copied from the clipboard into the Experiment source window, but using the preamble of the root document.

Comment: Nice trick indeed +

Answer (score 10):

Regarding your first question: the most noticeable speedup I've witnessed so far can be achieved by compiling to DVI instead of PDF. You may not be able to do that depending on the packages you use, however, but you could give it a try.

Answer (score 9):

Personally, I use the `-interaction=batchmode` option to prevent verbose output. Also, for the first runs (except the last), you can use `-draftmode` option:

```
-draftmode
   Sets \pdfdraftmode so pdfTeX doesn't write a PDF and doesn't read 
   any included images, thus speeding up execution.
```

In case of error (`$? -ne 0`), it is sufficient to tail the `log` file. 
You can see the full code on [Github](https://github.com/Falkor/Makefiles/blob/devel/latex/Makefile).

Comment: If you don't generate a PDF how do you preview the layout?

Comment: Normally you use `-draftmode` in the first two of the three runs before the last—that's why you use it "for the first runs (except the last)", as the post says.

Comment: For reducing console output the actual question is [compiling - Reducing the console output of LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/reducing-the-console-output-of-latex)

Answer (score 7):

### Math Accents

Math accents can slow down a compilation.  To speed up a document with many of these you can use the `\accentedsymbol` command defined in [amsxtra](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/) subpackage of the [amslatex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amslatex) package.  In the example below, `\vx` can be used for `\vect{x}` but will not take the time required to place the accents (arrows on bold symbols for example). Note that since the typesetting is done out of context, some issues can arise (the size will not be small in a superscript for example), so for the final version you should redefine `\accentedsymbol` to simply define a macro that will get expanded everywhere *in context.*

```
\usepackage{amsxtra}
%\renewcommand\accentedsymbol[2]{\def#1{#2}}  % Uncomment for final version
\accentedsymbol{\vx}{\vect{x}}
```

Note that there are limits to how many symbols you can store this way.

### Kpathsea

Not really a LaTeX issue per se, but `kpathsea` can be a huge performance hit if you are recursively searching directories and/or your `ls-R` databases are not up-to-date.  You can see what it is doing by setting

```
export KPATHSEA_DEBUG=1
```

before you run `latex`.  If it is searching many places, then this can be a huge slow-down.  Details can be found [in the manual](http://www.tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html#Slow-path-searching).  (I had a huge performance hit when I accidentally recursively linked a texmf tree deep within another tree for a package I was writing.)

Answer (score 7):

Don't load `inputenc` and/or `fontenc` if they are not necessarily needed because:

> The inputenc–fontenc combination seems slow and cumbersome, but it’s
> safe.

cited from [Why bother with inputenc and fontenc?](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-why-inp-font)

Comment: This solution is only really gonna be helpful for English documents; as soon as you use about any character outside of the ASCII range, you'll need these packages.

Answer (score 6):

It is not about "speeding up" but "how to work when latex is really slow".

I use kile+okular.

1. In the setting of okular uncheck "reload document on file change".
2. Add "reload button" to the toolbar of okular

After that you can continue to read pdf file, and reload it only when it is ready.

Answer (score 6):

I made a new Python script/module/package for this purpose.

https://github.com/user202729/tex-fast-recompile

(unlike other answers, this does not *actually* speed up the *compilation*, but it makes the PDF appear faster after the source code is edited)

I'll quote a section from the readme/documentation:

> ### How does it work?
>
> The principle is very simple. Notice that while the user want fast refresh, the file does not change very frequently.
>
> As such, we start the compiler *before* the file has changed to process the "preamble", then when the file changed we
> continue processing the rest of the file.
>
> A graph for illustration:
>
> **Before:**
>
> (each `*` represents a file change, `|--.--|` represents a compilation where the `.` marks where the preamble processing is done)
>
> ```
> +----------------------------------------------------> Time
>      *          *                *           *
>      |--.--|    |--.--|          |--.--|     |--.--|
> ```
>
> **After:**
>
> ```
> +----------------------------------------------------> Time
>      *          *                *           *
>      |--.--|--. --|--.           --|--.      --|
> ```
>
> It can be easily seen that after the change, it only takes 2 instead of 5 time unit
> from when the file is saved to when the change is reflected in the PDF.

---

Note on other known methods: (mentioned in the comments etc., collected here for convenience)

### Precompile the preamble

There are a few guides on this.

- [Ultrafast PDFLaTeX with precompiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79493/107497)

  - answer has a guide of `mylatexformat` package
  - links to: https://web.archive.org/web/20160712215709/http://www.howtotex.com:80/tips-tricks/faster-latex-part-iv-use-a-precompiled-preamble/
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521482/250119

  example how to precompile preamble with LuaTeX without `mylatexformat` (tested and does work)
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269052/250119

  - tutorial of `mylatex` package (note that this is older than `mylatexformat`)
- [How to speed up pdflatex for a very large document on MacOS X?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15604/250119)

  - mentions `latexdaemon`
  - answer has a guide of precompiling without `mylatexformat` package
  - links to: https://web.archive.org/web/20150406152732/https://magic.aladdin.cs.cmu.edu/2007/11/02/precompiled-preamble-for-latex/

#### Note

[Precompile header with xelatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49295/250119) explain it doesn't work with XeTeX/LuaTeX in some cases.

### Externalize TikZ graphics

Refer to [Externalizing TikZ-Images takes very long](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/477859/107497)

You can also parallelize TikZ-externalize for some extra performance, refer to https://tikz.dev/library-external#tikz/external/mode (`mode=list and make`) for instruction; or refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151255/250119.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your file system, file read/write times might be slowing *latex down. If you are on a Unix like system, you could keep all your resources in RAM. 
To do so you would first mount a ramdisk:

```
mkdir /mnt/ramdisk;
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=64M tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk;
```

(be sure to pick a sufficiently large size so your entire project including all resources will fit)

Than every time you want to rebuild, you would run:

```
rsync --archive --human-readable --progress --update --exclude=\"thesis.pdf\" . /mnt/ramdisk; 
cd /mnt/ramdisk; 
pdflatex thesis.tex; 
cd /path/to/your/thesis;
```

This syncs all changes you may have made since the last run (using rsync) and than invokes *latex on that copy of your files. The output is found in `/mnt/ramdisk/thesis.pdf`. I will simply open this in my viewer but at least in some circumstances one might like to sacrifice some time and copy the result to the original location (`cp /mnt/ramdisk/thesis.pdf thesis.pdf`).

This worked really well for me, as I used this setup to bring down compile times from 45 to 3 seconds.

Comment: How can I find the size required? Can I take size of complete folder with all tex files and images?

Comment: Yes, take the size of all images, tex files and the pdf output and add a view MB just to be on the save side. If your value is to low (latex should give you an error like "cannot read/write file" if that is the case) you can always increase it (maybe using `mount -o remount ...`). Just don't be too generous. You can use `free` to check how much RAM is available and you don't want to use significant parts of your RAM unless you really know what you are doing. On my 8GB RAM laptop I wouldn't want to use more than 1GB or 2GB.

Comment: Thanks for explanation!

Comment: Sometimes there's already a RAM-disk at `/tmp/` -- although check UNIX sites for more details.

Comment: This tip more than halved the compile time for me on a large document! 

Answer (score 5):

1. For a large document, I would suggest  making seperate tex files and using `\include{filename}` to include these files into the main file. Then, in the preamble, you can add command `\includeonly{filename1}` to start working on the file. There has been a quick fix around to comment out the code at `\include` to temporarily remove the files you are not using, but it disturbs the aux files. So, it's not recommended.
2. Do not use `todonotes` package. It seems that i am not the only one who has an slowing down issue with this package.
3. Use draftmode. It specially helps when you have a lot of images and it can be declared in the very beginning. I choose to keep the declaration code in individual lines so it's simpler to just comment/uncomment the lines to switch draftmode on/off.

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
draft
]{article}
```

4. Don't compile every now and then. It's probably not applicable to you or many others here, but people recently migrating from WYSIWYG softwares like MS word are more used to seeing a compiled document everytime. It helps to get used to read the TEX code for how it is.

Comment: As for 4, I disagree for large input documents because this contradicts my experience.  If I recompile too seldom, the compiler throws errors (e.g, due to my own typos or to package deficiencies), and these errors are sometimes cryptic and hence extremely difficult to debug because it's unknown which of a dozen changes of mine exactly caused them. As for the draft option, it's an interesting one; thx!

Answer (score 4):

I have a little tip:

If you want to include lots of figures, try to make them in vector graphics (`.svg`, `.pdf`, `.ps`), rather than raster graphics (`.jpg`, `.png`).

In my practice, a latex file containing 20 pages & 22 figures takes 56 seconds to compile when all figures are in `.png`, but only 4 seconds when I replace all of them with `.pdf` figures.

This may help people like me preparing latex draft for journal publication, since plots made with Python Matplotlib, IDL, Matlab, Origin or Excel can be easily exported in `.pdf` format.

Comment: PDF may contain also compressed BMP graphics (which is rasterized), so a simple conversion of any image into PDF won't help by itself. You have to be knowing what you are doing or be lucky.

Comment: @AlMa0 Thank you. That's very helpful reminder. This method does not work if one have already raster images and convert them into .pdf . It works when the figure can be exported to vector graphics when it's produced. E.g., ```fig.savefig('image.pdf')``` in Python, and ```save image as - pdf``` in Excel.

Answer (score 3):

So, What I did to handle the costly compilation is that, I first split up the document into the several chapters and every chapter into its own file, using the \input command. The main document has all the \input statements.
 
***Example:***
Inside the main_file.tex

```
\input{chapter1}
\input{chapter1_results}
\input{chapter2}
\input{chapter3}
```

---

Only the ones that are critical are not commented out. 'chapter1_results.tex' takes a lot of time to compile because of presence of figures. So I do the following, and its fast as hell.

Inside the main_file.tex

```
\input{chapter1}
%\input{chapter1_results}
\input{chapter2}
\input{chapter3}
```

Comment: This is very similar to [Leo Liu's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8805/5764).

Comment: Why don't you use `\includeonly` as described in Leo Liu's answer?

Comment: You are absolutely right! thanks for pointing out. I didnt know there was an \include command unitl now... I looked for \input, but didnt find it... Read the first two answers and glanced over the other comments. I should delete it right? \include makes the whole file a separate logical unit, where as \input just copy&pastes the content. I still find that commenting is easier than typing and removing \includeonly every time you need a file! I guess it might still be useful.

Comment: There's also the `standalone` package, so you can configure such that the individual files can be compiled manually (instead of editing the main file).

Answer (score 2):

Guess I'm pretty late to the party, but I use something that has not been mentioned here. My documents contain a significant amount of very high quality images, so I make two copies of the image file with one low resolution jpg and one high resolution png. I rename the files such that they have the suffix LOWRES.jpg or HIGHRES.png (I use png because that's what the image making software exports to). And I made a macro in TeXstudio that switches between the two image files.

This is some of my images in my images folder of my tex document:

[image]

And in my tex document I would have something like `\includegraphics[width=5cm]{methanalLOWRES.jph}` And the suffix would be changed by the macro below depending on whether I want to quickly compile a draft or compile to the best quality (which takes a significantly longer time). I use this in conjunction with `\includeonly` and it has signficantly reduced the compilation time.

```
%SCRIPT

scope = editor.document().cursor(0, 0, -1);

if (editor.search("HIGHRES.png", "g") > 0) {
  editor.replace("HIGHRES.png","g",scope,"LOWRES.jpg");

} else {
  if (editor.search("LOWRES.jpg", "g") > 0) {
    editor.replace("LOWRES.jpg","g",scope,"HIGHRES.png");
  }
}
```

I added this as a script macro on TeXstudio, so I am unsure if it will work on TeXmaker or other LaTeX editors, but the script is fairly basic and you should be able to implement your own for your own situation.

EDIT:
I use this website to resize my images https://bulkresizephotos.com. I simply just make the width 800px, and it outputs a lower resolution jpg file which I download (and unzip if multiple files were submitted). I believe imagemagick can do something similar, but I have not looked into it.

I just saw YuppieNetworking's answer above, which is very similar to my answer, nonetheless I will keep my answer here should someone want to use the script

Comment: You could also define a macro: `\newcommand{\res}{LOWRES}`, so that you could then `\includegraphics{methanal\res.jpg}`.  Then you could switch the macro when you what the high quality version.

Comment: ImageMagick: `for i in *HIGHRES.png ; do convert -resize 800x $i ${i%HIGHRES.png}LOWRES.png ; done`.

Answer (score 1):

It is slow and will get even slower (which is an empirically well-established issue for all software development and not only for LaTeX).  As usual, the ultimately best way may be to improve the architecture and the source code of (La)TeX and its packages and clean up the messy code in the process.  That is, rewrite everything from scratch (which seems to be a project attainable only for folks having both finances and decades to spend on typesetting for the rest of their lifetime), starting with the goals and the documentation (i.e, how things should be).  Outdated interfaces might be left out in the process, which, ultimately, would lead to a different and incompatible typesetting system.

The way out is to become a serious typesetting developer or to learn to live with what you get, in particular, slow compilation.

Not being a serious LaTeX developer, I have two versions of any of my large books: a draft version and a clean version.  A book has two main files (say, draft.tex and clean.tex, where draft.tex defines my own macro `\draft` and inputs clean.tex). The program `latex` compiles the draft version quickly into DVI (sometimes followed by dvips), and `lualatex`/`xelatex` compiles the clean version slowly into PDF. Moreover, the document source is split into many files so that I can edit them while both `latex` and `lualatex`/`xelatex` run in the background.  The only disadvantage is that your document source will likely have to contain several occurrences of `\ifdefined\draft…\else…\fi` (most often in the preamble and seldom in the main text), e.g., when loading different fonts and hyperlink-related packages.

Comment: (For reference Typst took 4 years to be developed, and at the moment it still has lots of bugs left as well as other issues.)

Comment: @user202729 I presume you mean the time according to the wall clock, which is a rather rough measure. How many man-years, i.e., the pure user time, was spent on Typst?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution.

## Decompress the format file in advance

Technically this method relies on internal implementation details of the engines, but it works anyway.

You can do the following. Assuming the file to be compiled is `helloworld.tex`.

```bash
gunzip < "$(kpsewhich -engine=luahbtex lualatex.fmt)" > lualatexunzipped.fmt
lualatex '&lualatexunzipped' helloworld.tex
```

The first command should be done **once**, and keep the resulting generated `lualatexunzipped.fmt` file in the same directory as the TeX file (or somewhere that is pointed to by `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXFORMATS`).

Then, the second command should be used to compile a file instead of the usual `lualatex helloworld.tex`.

Speed up:

```bash
$ time lualatex helloworld.tex
real    0m0.775s
user    0m0.546s
sys     0m0.215s
$ cp "$(kpsewhich -engine=luahbtex lualatex.fmt)" lualatexa.fmt
$ time lualatex '&lualatexa' helloworld.tex
real    0m0.642s
user    0m0.490s
sys     0m0.145s
$ time lualatex '&lualatexunzipped' helloworld.tex
real    0m0.543s
user    0m0.382s
sys     0m0.155s
```

Note that if the format file name is `lualatex` then apparently `kpathsea` will be invoked to search *something*, which takes another approximately 0.1 seconds.
Thus, copying the format file to `./lualatexa.fmt` alone (without decompression) already save 0.1s.

You can save ≈ 0.1 to 0.2 seconds per compilation this way. Significant if your file is small.

### Explanation

First, read [my answer on precompiled preamble](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/687427/250119) to understand what `.fmt` format files are.

Then, roughly speaking, this is because the implementation of the TeX engines use the gzip format for the `.fmt` files, and [`gzdopen` function](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/zlib-gzdopen-1.html) is used to read the file. However, it has a [compression level 0](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/zlib-deflateinit2.html) which states that the input is the same as the output.

As long as the decompressed file is not a valid gzip archive (and that `gzdopen` does not complain when the level being passed in is different from the level of the actual archive), everything should be fine.

### Note 2

If the decompressed file happens to be a valid gzip archive (perhaps because [it starts with the magic number `1f 8b`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3703300/5267751)) then
you might be able to use the following to compress it at level 0:

```bash
python -c 'import sys, gzip; sys.stdout.buffer.write(gzip.compress(sys.stdin.buffer.read(), compresslevel=0))' < lualatexunzipped.fmt > lualatexzipped0.fmt
```

My version of `gzip` does not accept `-0` as input, although it accepts `-1` until `-9`.

### Note

Unsurprisingly, this will bloat the format file size.

From LuaTeX source code:

```c
/*tex

    Tests has shown that a level 3 compression is the most optimal tradeoff
    between file size and load time.

*/

#define COMPRESSION "R3"
```

### For other engines

```bash
gunzip < "$(kpsewhich -engine=xetex xelatex.fmt)" > xelatexunzipped.fmt
xelatex '&xelatexunzipped' helloworld.tex

gunzip < "$(kpsewhich -engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt)" > pdflatexunzipped.fmt
pdflatex '&pdflatexunzipped' helloworld.tex
```

### Combine this solution with precompiled preamble

Similarly, this solution can be combined with [precompiled preamble](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/687427/250119) for even more speedup.

### Dangerous: modify the user format files

Do the following.

```bash
mktexfmt pdflatex
pdflatex_fmt="$(kpsewhich -engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt)" 
mv "$pdflatex_fmt" "$pdflatex_fmt".gz
gunzip "$pdflatex_fmt".gz

mktexfmt xelatex
xelatex_fmt="$(kpsewhich -engine=xetex xelatex.fmt)" 
mv "$xelatex_fmt" "$xelatex_fmt".gz
gunzip "$xelatex_fmt".gz

mktexfmt lualatex
lualatex_fmt="$(kpsewhich -engine=luahbtex lualatex.fmt)" 
mv "$lualatex_fmt" "$lualatex_fmt".gz
gunzip "$lualatex_fmt".gz
```

In each block, the first command creates a per-user format file.
Read the warning.

```
*************************************************************
*                                                           *
* WARNING: you are switching to fmtutil's per-user formats. *
*         Please read the following warnings!               *
*                                                           *
*************************************************************

You have run fmtutil-user (as opposed to fmtutil-sys) for the first time;
this has created format files which are local to your personal account.

From now on, any changes in system formats will *not* be automatically
reflected in your files; furthermore, running fmtutil-sys will no longer
have any effect for you.

As a consequence, you yourself have to rerun fmtutil-user after any
change in the system directories. For example, when one of the LaTeX or
other format source files changes, which happens frequently.
See https://tug.org/texlive/scripts-sys-user.html for details.

If you want to undo this, remove the files mentioned above.
```

The remaining 3 commands just decompress that file.

Note, however, that this solution is slightly slower than the solution above because of kpathsea path search for something.

### References

- `texdoc pdftex` documents the usage of `TEXFORMATS` and other Web2c variables.

Answer (score 0):

There's this solution...

First, the disadvantages

- only works on POSIX systems
- requires LuaLaTeX
- somewhat cumbersome (for now)
- requires shell-escape and manually install some Lua library
- may fail to work for weird reasons, or damage your computer

The only advantages are...

- **real incremental compilation!** <sup>(*)</sup>
- cheaper than BaKoMa <sup>(†)</sup>
- *supports* LuaLaTeX

<sup>(*)</sup>: My attempts to use *precompiled preamble* (which is basically user-written *format* file) in LuaLaTeX has all failed, partially because Lua states and some other things cannot be dumped. <sub>maybe I should just switch back to pdflatex for the speed, especially now I am better at forcing TeX to do what I want</sub>
<sup>(†)</sup>: There's now WYSIWYG editing though. (unfortunately)

---

The basic idea is to use `fork()` to spawn new process when part of the file change, instead of re-run it from scratch.

Proof of concept code:

```latex
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=5cm,paperwidth=5cm,margin=0.6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{luapackageloader}
\begin{document}

% you can write some LaTeX here too

\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
-- load the package
package.path = "/usr/share/lua/5.3/?.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/?/init.lua;/usr/lib/lua/5.3/?.lua;/usr/lib/lua/5.3/?/init.lua;./?.lua;./?/init.lua"
package.cpath = "/usr/lib/lua/5.3/?.so;/usr/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so;./?.so"
local posix=require "posix"

function copyfile(source, target)
    local infile=io.open(source, "rb")
    local outfile=io.open(target, "wb")
    outfile:write(infile:read("*all"))
    infile:close()
    outfile:close()
end

--first backup the partial PDF content
copyfile(tex.jobname..".pdf", "backup-"..tex.jobname..".pdf")
copyfile(tex.jobname..".log", "backup-"..tex.jobname..".log") -- strictly speaking this is not necessary

while true do
    local pid = posix.fork()
    if pid == 0 then
        -- is child, compile b.tex
        break
    else
        -- is parent
        posix.wait(pid) 
        print("======== Press enter to recompile ========")
        io.read()
        -- **critical**: restore the partial PDF content
        copyfile("backup-"..tex.jobname..".pdf", tex.jobname..".pdf")
        copyfile("backup-"..tex.jobname..".log", tex.jobname..".log")
    end
end
```

```latex
\end{luacode*}

\input{b.tex}

\end{document}
```

First create a file named `b.tex`, put in some content.

Then run `lualatex a.tex` where `a.tex` is the main file (above).

When you edit `b.tex`, press enter in the lualatex process. It will regenerate `a.pdf` instantaneously... as long as `b.tex` isn't too long.

Comment: Actually this solution is quite buggy and more likely to fail than not.

Comment: Actually no-backup (other than hard-link to preserve the (busy) file) seems to be sufficient for pdf and synctex. But aux is the odd one, it doesn't seek.

Comment: Another thing (unrelated to this answer however), \usepackage speed is improved in newer expl3 version, so upgrading might make it faster, see https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60905323#60905323 for some discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

## Use Tectonic

> Tectonic is a modernized, complete, self-contained TeX/LaTeX engine, powered by XeTeX and TeXLive.

-- https://tectonic-typesetting.github.io/en-US/

If you're using XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX and needs its Unicode support, Tectonic appears to be a good option. Otherwise, there is always the option of switching to PDFLaTeX.

To my surprise, even though it is based on XeLaTeX, it is actually faster than XeLaTeX (for the files I tested).

I don't know why it's faster (but a guess is that it avoids the `kpathsea` path lookup overhead).

### Benchmark

For the following file:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0, 0) to [bend left] (2, 1);
    \draw (0.7, -0.4) -- (0.8, 1.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I benchmark it with `hyperfine` and get:

```bash
[tmp]$ hyperfine --warmup=1 'tectonic --keep-intermediates a.tex' 'xelatex a.tex'
Benchmark 1: tectonic --keep-intermediates a.tex
  Time (mean ± σ):     643.8 ms ±  53.5 ms    [User: 551.1 ms, System: 88.6 ms]
  Range (min … max):   594.0 ms … 742.8 ms    10 runs
 
Benchmark 2: xelatex a.tex
  Time (mean ± σ):     834.2 ms ±  43.5 ms    [User: 484.7 ms, System: 345.3 ms]
  Range (min … max):   792.2 ms … 903.7 ms    10 runs
 
Summary
  tectonic --keep-intermediates a.tex ran
    1.30 ± 0.13 times faster than xelatex a.tex
```

For the following file:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

The benchmark is:

```bash
Benchmark 1: tectonic --keep-intermediates a.tex
  Time (mean ± σ):     478.7 ms ±   4.9 ms    [User: 391.1 ms, System: 84.5 ms]
  Range (min … max):   472.1 ms … 485.8 ms    10 runs
 
Benchmark 2: xelatex a.tex
  Time (mean ± σ):     522.6 ms ±  13.3 ms    [User: 348.0 ms, System: 184.9 ms]
  Range (min … max):   512.5 ms … 553.6 ms    10 runs
 
Summary
  tectonic --keep-intermediates a.tex ran
    1.09 ± 0.03 times faster than xelatex a.tex
```