# XeLaTeX Quiet Output and Halt on Error

Tags: xetex

I find the output of XeLaTeX excessively verbose. I am really just interested in errors (not warnings), and the offending line number. I also would like xelatex to halt (exit) on error. Is there a magic incantation that can produce this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get rid of ALL warnings you can load the [`silence`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/silence) package

```
\usepackage{silence}
```

and then issue the command

```
\WarningsOff*
```

Have a look at its documentation for selective warnings filtering and errors filtering, if you need it.

Just remember that warnings are what they are supposed to be: they warn you about something wrong in your document.

---

For your latter request, if you want xelatex to halt on errors (and exit) add `--halt-on-error` to the command line, otherwise, if you want a prompt where to decide what to do, add `--interaction=errorstopmode` to the command line.

Comment: --halt-on-error worked as expected, but it did not indicate the line number where the error occurred. The `silence` package seems to have no effect: https://gist.github.com/mrichman/7876806 I really want to hide all that `(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex` verbosity.

Comment: @MarkRichman 1. I can't see any error in the log file. 2. `silence` is certainly not perfect and can miss something... 3. Without a MWE it is difficult to say what it misses...

Comment: Actually, I'm giving `rubber` a try. I think it may do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

With TeX Live a Perl script called `texfot` (by Karl Berry) is available.

Running

```
texfot --ignore '(Warning|Overfull|Underfull)' pdflatex test
```

on the file `test.tex` that follows

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\hbox to 0pt{aaa} % Overfull \hbox

\hbox to 100pt{x} % Underfull \hbox

{\fontsize{125}{0}\selectfont a} % font warning

\foo % undefined control sequence

\end{document}
```

the output on the console is

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/texfot: invoking: pdflatex test
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 \foo
! Emergency stop.
l.11 \foo
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

You can customize the regexp string to your will if you find something else should be ignored.

The `.log` file is still produced entirely:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.12.23)  6 JAN 2017 23:58
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (./warnerr.aux)
\openout1 = `warnerr.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.

Overfull \hbox (15.00005pt too wide) detected at line 5
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 aaa
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line 7
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 x
 []


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <125> not available
(Font)              size <24.88> substituted on input line 9.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 \foo
          % undefined control sequence
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.11 \foo
          % undefined control sequence
End of file on the terminal!


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 200 strings out of 493013
 2160 string characters out of 6133342
 53632 words of memory out of 5000000
 3833 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3939 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,0n,17p,111b,64s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying a whole day I ended up dong my own python script with pyparsing:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# file: xelatex-clean.py
def spoil(l):
    if type(l) == list:
        if len(l) == 0:
            return ''
        elif len(l) == 1:
            return spoil(l[0])
    return l

def pprint(nested, max_level, level = 0, indent = '    '):
    for i,c in enumerate(nested):
        nested[i] = spoil(c)
    for c in nested:
        if type(c) != list:
            print (indent*level + c.replace('\n','\n' + indent*level))
        elif level < max_level:
            pprint (c, max_level, level + 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from pyparsing import nestedExpr, OneOrMore, Word, printables
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print ("Usage: xelatex document.tex | xelatex-clean.py <nesting-level>")
    xelatex_output = sys.stdin.read()
    l = nestedExpr('(',')',content=OneOrMore(Word(printables+' \n',excludeChars='()'))).parseString('(%s)'%xelatex_output).asList()[0]
    pprint(l,int(sys.argv[1]))
```

The spoil function removes empty or inline parentheses that otherwise would fill the output with empty spaces. I didn't spend much time to see if I could use the standard pprint function instead of my own.
Hope it helps.

**Usage:**

```
<xelatex command> | xelatex-clean.py <nesting-level>
```

**Example 1:**

```
> xelatex document.tex | xelatex-clean.py 0

This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 
TeX Live 2013
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode

see the transcript file for additional information
Output written on document.pdf 
2 pages
.
Transcript written on document.log.

[Finished in 2.4s]
```

**Example 2:**

```
> xelatex document.tex | xelatex-clean.py 1

This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 
TeX Live 2013
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode

    ./document.tex
    LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
    Babel <3.9g> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.

    /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/font/beamerfontthem
    eprofessionalfonts.sty
    /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/font/beamerfontthem
    eserif.sty
    /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
    s/tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex
    /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/silence/silence.sty
    ./document.aux
    /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd
    *geometry* driver: auto-detecting
    *geometry* detected driver: xetex
    ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros 
    ./document.out
    ./document.out
    /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translato
    r-basic-dictionary/translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict
    /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translato
    r-bibliography-dictionary/translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict
    /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translato
    r-environment-dictionary/translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict
    /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translato
    r-months-dictionary/translator-months-dictionary-English.dict
    /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translato
    r-numbers-dictionary/translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict
    /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translato
    r-theorem-dictionary/translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict
    ./document.nav
    /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmtt.fd

    [1] 
    /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
    /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
    <use  "../figs/figure1.pdf" >
    <use  "../figs/figure2.pdf" >
    <use  "../figs/figure3.pdf" >
    <use  "../figs/figure4.pdf" >
    Overfull \hbox 
    1.99998pt too wide
    in paragraph at lines 132--132
     [] 

    Overfull \vbox 
    16.81339pt too high
    detected at line 132
    [2] 
    ./document.aux
see the transcript file for additional information
Output written on document.pdf 
2 pages
.
Transcript written on document.log.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(...)
-interaction=STRING     set interaction mode (STRING=batchmode/nonstopmode/
                          scrollmode/errorstopmode)
```

Run xelatex with `-interaction=batchmode -halt-on-error`

Comment: Related: [How to reduce terminal output from xelatex?](http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2016-August/026790.html); [What reasons (if any) are there for compiling in interactive mode?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25267/5764)

Comment: I think it is `xelatex -interaction=batchmode -halt-on-error main.tex` that suppresses the output in terminal.

Comment: That reduces the output, but doesn't eliminate it. I would really like it to not say anything unless something goes wrong, and in the case something does, complain about it on stderr, not stdout.