# TeXstudio: how to automate LaTeX biber sequence of compilation

Tags: compiling, automation, texstudio

I'm a bit confused about how to configure TeXstudio to use `biber`. It's not that I can't find a way, I'm just wondering what is the intended way, i.e. coming from WinEdt I'm used to that "Build" or "Compile" triggers a `latex biber latex latex sequence`. But I had to find out that TeXstudio is apparently not configured that way by default. By default, "Build and View" triggers `txs:///compile | txs:///view`, and `compile`, according to [the manual](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/texstudio/code/trunk/utilities/usermanual_en.html) "calls `txs:///pdflatex` that calls the actual `pdflate[x]`". There is not even a toolbar button to trigger `biber`. I had to look for it in the menus and set it off manually (or press `F11`). This makes no sense to me, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something?

Here is what I've done: I now have changed the default compiler to trigger `latex biber latex latex` (or rather: `txs:///compile | txs:///bibliography | txs:///compile | txs:///compile | txs:///view`, to be precise). But then I noticed the "Repeat contained compilation commands" buttons which kinda seemed a nice idea but didnt really make sense to me, so I turned  that off for the default compiler since I want to call it once before `biber` and twice after `biber`, which is not possible if it's set to repeat. So I'm kinda wondering if I'm just not getting the TeXstudio logic or why does it look like it does... It's so strange.

P.S. Just to clarify: this question is not really about `biber`. It's just that I'm using `biber`. I guess the same questions would arise using `bibtex`.

Update: I admit that my exact question was not so clear. I guess I am trying to understand how TeXstudio runs the compilation sequence and how it can be customized, i.e. what the logic of the (advanced) configuration options is.

Comment: Hi Christoph, what is your precise question here, sorry could not follow you.

Comment: I recommend the usage of `arara`. The documentation has an extra part about the configuration of editors. http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arara

Comment: `arara` is indeed an interesting tool, but it does not solve but rather circumvents my question.

Answer (score 32):

To make TeXStudio, currently version 2.12.2, use `biber` by default, click

> Options > Configure TeXstudio > Build > Default Bibliography > Biber

Then you have to configure the command in options if it isn't set by default.

> Options > Configure TeXstudio > Commands > Biber > Choose file > (in Ubuntu 16.10) /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/biber

Pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> should now run your desired sequence.

Comment: Hm. True. But what is the logic behind this? I don't get it. `F1` triggers the sequence defined under "Build & View", right? And there it says by default: `txs:///compile | txs:///view`, right? And `txs:///compile`, calls `pdflatex`, and nothing else (according to the manual). So where does all the other stuff come from?

Comment: Well, documentation is short on that point. The logic is as follows. If you have advanced options enabled, you'll see an entry "Check and update bibliography before compiling" under Options > Configure TeXStudio > Build.

If there are changes in the bibliography this triggers `txs:///compile | txs:///bibliography | txs:///compile` before executing the actual "Build & View".

Comment: @TimHoffmann: I see. That does explain a great deal. How does TeXstudio check for changes? I suspect that this did not work properly when I first tried to compile my document and that's why I started to wonder about the configuration...

Comment: @Christoph, [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/mailman/texstudio-list/thread/008101cd2886%245d130a30%2417391e90%24%40hiskp.uni-bonn.de/#msg29209514) discussion says that `conditionally-recompile-bibliography` simply "calls recompile-bibliography, but only if the bib files have been changed". Also, [the tooltip for this checkbox says](https://github.com/svn2github/texstudio-trunk/blob/612ba733b62322cf8ab8feb5ad09a80535fc070b/configdialog.ui#L678-L680)"Runs txs:///recompile-bibliography, if bib-files were changed"

Comment: @Igor there is a case with multiple bibliographies where the logic is flawed. For example, if you move around the `\printbibliography` you need a new `biber` command to get a correct re-numbering. Other tools (LyX?) seem to figure this out.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 22.04 with **texlive-full** installed. I follow this answer, unfortunately, I cannot find the folder that store biber. My work-around solution is to replace the `<unknown>` in *TexStudio -> Options -> Configure TexStudio -> Commands -> Biber* by `biber %.bcf`.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed TeXstudio and encountered a similar problem. Let me share the solution, maybe it will help someone. I use Miktex under Windows. I compile with pdfLaTeX, and use BibTeX and Natbib for bibliography.

***Problem***. After I change the bibliography style (`\bibliographystyle` command) in the `.tex` document and run "Build & View", the format of bibliography in the `.pdf` file remains the same (despite "Check and update bibliography before compiling" is ON). Using `compile bibliography compile compile` sequence for "Build & View" (as suggested by OP) increases the compilation time significantly.

***Solution***. Following the advice from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8792/214965, I added `-draftmode` argument to the first two compilations. However, this triggered the error "Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations" whenever I changed bibliography style from a one with numbered citations to a one with author-year citations. As a workaround, I preceded the sequence with a command to clean all auxiliary files. The resulted configuration (in the "Build" section) looks as follows.

- Set the command `Precompile` = `pdflatex.exe -draftmode -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`. *That command was empty in my config but if you do not want to override it, add a custom command instead.*
- Add the custom command `clean-files` = `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C del "?am.aux" "?am.bbl" "?am.blg" "?am.log" "?am.out"`
- Add the custom command `compile-full` = `txs:///clean-files | txs:///pre-compile | txs:///bibliography | txs:///pre-compile | txs:///compile | txs:///view`

After that I added `txs:///compile-full` to the menu and the toolbar in order to use it instead of "Build & view".

Answer (score 0):

The heuristics behind the "automatically try one more time" is indeed interesting to know. It looks like I found the corresponding parts of code.

The main idea is to [check](https://github.com/svn2github/texstudio-trunk/blob/25d87b24ca6fe20a6ff5625eea4bda264a6cafd4/latexlog.cpp#L127-L131) for a specific hard-coded pattern, `No file.*\\.(aux|toc)`.
Moreover, if "[check and update bibliography before compiling](https://github.com/svn2github/texstudio-trunk/blob/25d87b24ca6fe20a6ff5625eea4bda264a6cafd4/configdialog.ui#L677-L686)" checkbox [is checked](https://github.com/svn2github/texstudio-trunk/blob/25d87b24ca6fe20a6ff5625eea4bda264a6cafd4/configmanager.cpp#L1473), it also [checks for "missing citations"](https://github.com/svn2github/texstudio-trunk/blob/25d87b24ca6fe20a6ff5625eea4bda264a6cafd4/texmaker.cpp#L4944-L4961) by looking for `Citation <...> undefined`.

Automatically checking the compilation log is a very nice feature. But it's hard-coded and only supports bibtex. AFAIU, biber support cannot be added by simply modifying corresponding regexps - for example, if I delete all references to a specific article - I won't disapper from the references list, (unless I run [full sequence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/264315/143086)), and I there would be no warnings to "catch".