# Citing the appendix of a paper without lowercase letter added

Tags: biblatex, appendices

I am using Biblatex and I got the following problem: I am citing a paper quite a lot and the appendix to this paper only very few times.

Right now, I am using the solution:

```
@article{co:2004,
author = {T. Coven},
title = {Title A},
journaltitle = {The X Journal},
date = {2004}
}
@article{coapp:2004,
author = {T. Coven},
title = {Appendix to Title A},
journaltitle = {The X Journal},
date = {2004}
}
```

But this turns into: Coven (2004a) and Coven (2004b). I think this is a bad idea, if the appendix is used so rarely? How do you solve this? Any recommendations welcome.

My latest idea was to cite instead: Coven (2004) for the normal paper and sthg like 'Appendix to Coven (2004)' for the appendix. However, Biblatex always adds the lowercase letter 'b' to any further entry after the first one. How can I prevent this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline, headings=small,]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,
style=authoryear-icomp,
dashed=false,
autocite=footnote,
maxcitenames=3,
mincitenames=1,
maxbibnames=100,
firstinits=true,
sorting=nty
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{lib}

\begin{document}
\cite{co:2004} and \cite{coapp:2004}
\end{document}
```

I don't think it is important for this question, but here is my citation style [Please read only if required for this question!], taken from here: 
[Custom BibLaTeX style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151735/custom-biblatex-style)

```
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
\iffieldundef{labelyear}
  {}
  {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
   \printtext[parens]{% 
   \printfield{labelyear}%
   \printfield{extrayear}}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
    {}
    {%\printtext[parens]{%
       \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
       \iffieldsequal{year}{\thefield{datelabelsource}year}
         {\printdateextralabel}%
         {\printfield{labelyear}%
          \printfield{extrayear}}}}%}%

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{institution+location+date}{%
  \printlist{institution}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}
\renewbibmacro*{organization+location+date}{%
  \printlist{organization}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield[parens]{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
```

Comment: This seems quite hard to accomplish. How would `biblatex` know what paper is the appendix (of course, there could be an option you could specify)? What if you have two equally important papers from the same year, say 2004; of course one would be "2004a", the other "2004b"? What about their appendices?

Comment: @moewe yes I see. It was only an suggestion by me. Most of the papers I have read who quote these 2 papers also don't cite the appendix specifically. It seems strange to have '2004a' in the whole document, when all other papers use just '2004' instead. The appendix doesn't play such an important role. How would you solve it then?

Comment: Hmmm, If you need to cite both the paper and its appendix you should probably live with it. There are also ways to consolidate two entries into one `set`, maybe that's for you; or use Biber's related function together with `dataonly` in the appendix.

Comment: @moewe by deal with it you mean keep the 'a' and 'b' style as it is right?

Comment: Yup. I thinks this is the most consistent and least disruptive method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The appendix to a paper is part of the paper, so in general one shouldn't treat the appendix as a separate bibliography entry. The exception that proves the rule is an appendix by an author different from that of the main text body, especially if the text body isn't cited. In your case (same author, main text body as well as appendix cited), I strongly suggest to use a single bibliography entry. If you need to point out that certain citations refer to the appendix, use the second optional argument of your preferred citation command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{co:2004,
author = {T. Coven},
title = {Title A},
journaltitle = {The X Journal},
date = {2004}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite[99]{co:2004}.

Some text \autocite[Appendix to][101]{co:2004}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 because you're one of the best experts in `biblatex` ;-)