# Change 'Chapter' in @inbook to 'Appendix' for one BibLaTex entry

Tags: biblatex

I'm working on a thesis and I want to quote twice from one book using the type `@inbook`. Once I want to quote a regular chapter. This works fine and yields something like

> [1] AuthorA. "TitleA". In: Booktitle. Chap. 1.

The other quote is an appendix. My problem is that I can't manage to replace Chap. by App. in the Bibligraphy. I'd like to have something like

> [2] AuthorB. "TitleB". In: Booktitle. App. 4.

but instead just have an ugly A4 for appendix 4 in the chapter field

> [2] AuthorB. "TitleB". In: Booktitle. Chap. A4.

I managed to change Chap. to some other string with `\DefineBibliographyStrings` but obviously this changes all Chap. entries and thus does not solve my problem. Is there a way to change this for just one entry? Or do I have to create a new type?

My question is quite similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154591/citing-the-appendix-of-a-paper-without-lowercase-letter-added) but the author differs so I can not use the solution proposed there.

A MWE for the situation where I am stuck at:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
 @Inbook{CiteA,
  Title                    = {TitleA},
  Author                   = {AuthorA},
  Booktitle                = {Booktitle},
  Chapter                  = {1},
}
 @Inbook{CiteB,
  Title                    = {TitleB},
  Author                   = {AuthorB},
  Booktitle                = {Booktitle},
  Chapter                  = {A4},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: As the manual says, this field is controversial.  You could use a `note={App. A4}` (or perhaps a `subtitle`...) or not include the information in the bibliography and cite as `\cite[App. A4]{CiteB}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One could also tell `biblatex` whether to print "appendix" or "chapter" based on an option set in the `.bib` file.

First we define a switch (toggle) to toggle from "chapter" to "appendix" on a per-entry basis

```
\newtoggle{bib@appendix} % fallback is false
\DeclareEntryOption{appendix}[true]{\settoggle{bib@appendix}{#1}}
```

Obviously, we will need the "appendix" bib string (unlike Guido above, we will implement this in a separate `.lbx` file, so we can have both a full and an abbreviated version of the string; if you like you can use Guido's version instead)

```
\ProvidesFile{english-append.lbx}[2014/05/22 english with appendix]
\InheritBibliographyExtras{english}
\NewBibliographyString{appendix}
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit   = {english},
  appendix  = {{appendix}{app\adddot}},
}
```

The `.lbx` file must be put somewhere LaTeX can find it - in the MWE below it will be created with `filecontents`, if you plan to use it more often, you really should save it in an appropriate directory. It can then be loaded via `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-append}`.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{chapter}{%
   \iftoggle{bib@appendix}
     {\bibstring{appendix}}
     {\bibstring{chapter}}~#1}
```

Then we can toggle the "appendix" string via `options = {appendix}`, `CiteB` would look like this

```
@Inbook{CiteB,
  title     = {TitleB},
  author    = {AuthorB},
  booktitle = {Booktitle},
  chapter   = {A4},
  options   = {appendix}
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
 @Inbook{CiteA,
  Title                    = {TitleA},
  Author                   = {AuthorA},
  Booktitle                = {Booktitle},
  Chapter                  = {1},
}
 @Inbook{CiteB,
  title     = {TitleB},
  author    = {AuthorB},
  booktitle = {Booktitle},
  chapter   = {A4},
  options   = {appendix}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{filecontents*}{english-append.lbx}
    \ProvidesFile{english-append.lbx}[2014/05/22 english with appendix]
    \InheritBibliographyExtras{english}
    \NewBibliographyString{appendix}
    \DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
      inherit   = {english},
      appendix  = {{appendix}{app\adddot}},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-append}

\newtoggle{bib@appendix} % fallback is false
\DeclareEntryOption{appendix}[true]{\settoggle{bib@appendix}{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{chapter}{%
  \iftoggle{bib@appendix}
    {\bibstring{appendix}}
    {\bibstring{chapter}}~#1}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution: The idea is to change how the `chapter` field is printed based on the `key` value of an entry (stored in the `entrykey`  pseudo-field).

First of all, we create a new biblatex string for appendix.

```
\NewBibliographyString{appendix}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
appendix = {Appendix},
}
```

then, we change the formatting instructions for `chapter` using a switch (conditional) taking care of a particular value of the field `entrykey`.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{chapter}{%
   \iffieldequalstr{entrykey}
       {CiteB}
       {\bibstring{appendix}}
       {\bibstring{chapter}}~#1}
```

The output for the given MWE is:

[image]