# Custom biblatex citation style

Tags: biblatex, citing

With biblatex (+biber / lualatex) I wish to create a citation style as follows: the whole citation is within brackets and hyperlinked to the relevant bibliography entry, and has the form `Firstauthorname.year` with the addition of an alphabetic identifier if that form is ambiguous.

I could go some way by various package import options, but not quite far enough:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    style=authoryear,
    backend=biber,
    maxcitenames=1,
    uniquelist=false,
    ]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{one,
      author = {Alpha Bravo and Charlie Delta},
      title = {How to make cites and influence formatting},
      journal = {Journal of LateX typesetting},
      date = {2025},
    }
    @article{two,
      author = {Alpha Bravo and Echo Foxtrot},
      title = {Biblatex citations and where to find them},
      journal = {Journal of LateX sightseeing},
      date = {2025},
    }
    @article{three,
      author = {Charlie Delta and Echo Foxtrot},
      title = {The man who killed Don Knuth},
      journal = {Journal of LateX novelling},
      date = {2025},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l|l}
    Actual & Desired (need hyperlinks too) \\ \hline
    \cite{one} & [Bravo.2025a] \\
    \cite{two} & [Bravo.2025b] \\
    \cite{three} & [Delta.2025] \\
  \end{tabular}


  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the MWE]

There are lots of kind-of-duplicates-but-not-really, such as [Custom BibLaTeX style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151735/custom-biblatex-style) but I was not able to deduce what needs to be done.

The answer is *somewhere* in part 4 of the [biblatex manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), which I tried reading, but I cannot make heads or tails of it. Same thing for a direct dive in the source code of the bibliographic macros (`biblatex.def`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a borderline case between `authoryear` and `alphabetic` citation styles. Generally, I'd advise against abusing `alphabetic` for a style that is essentially an `authoryear` variation, but here it is not exactly clear to me what the style should be.

Since it is currently tricky to disable the "et al." (it will be possible in future `biblatex` versions: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/861), I'll present an `alphabetic` solution first. This solution mainly relies on `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    style=authoryear,
    citestyle=alphabetic,
    backend=biber,
    maxcitenames=1,
    maxalphanames=1,
    uniquelist=false,
    ]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \literal{.}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field{year}
  }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{one,
  author  = {Alpha Bravo and Charlie Delta},
  title   = {How to make cites and influence formatting},
  journal = {Journal of {\LaTeX} typesetting},
  date    = {2025},
}
@article{two,
  author  = {Alpha Bravo and Echo Foxtrot},
  title   = {Biblatex citations and where to find them},
  journal = {Journal of {\LaTeX} sightseeing},
  date    = {2025},
}
@article{three,
  author  = {Charlie Delta and Echo Foxtrot},
  title   = {The man who killed Don Knuth},
  journal = {Journal of {\LaTeX} novelling},
  date    = {2025},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
    Actual & Desired (need hyperlinks too) \\ \hline
    \cite{one} & [Bravo.2025a] \\
    \cite{two} & [Bravo.2025b] \\
    \cite{three} & [Delta.2025] \\
  \end{tabular}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [Bravo.2025a]//[Bravo.2025b]//[Delta.2025]]

---

In future versions of `biblatex` (v3.13 and above) you should be able to do something like the following. (I'm using my `biblatex-ext` bundle to be able to quickly change the parentheses to brackets.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    style=ext-authoryear,
    backend=biber,
    maxcitenames=1,
    uniquelist=false,
    nohashothers=true, nosortothers=true,
    ]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addperiod}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:family}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiven}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{one,
  author  = {Alpha Bravo and Charlie Delta},
  title   = {How to make cites and influence formatting},
  journal = {Journal of {\LaTeX} typesetting},
  date    = {2025},
}
@article{two,
  author  = {Alpha Bravo and Echo Foxtrot},
  title   = {Biblatex citations and where to find them},
  journal = {Journal of {\LaTeX} sightseeing},
  date    = {2025},
}
@article{three,
  author  = {Charlie Delta and Echo Foxtrot},
  title   = {The man who killed Don Knuth},
  journal = {Journal of {\LaTeX} novelling},
  date    = {2025},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
    Actual & Desired (need hyperlinks too) \\ \hline
    \autocite{one} & [Bravo.2025a] \\
    \autocite{two} & [Bravo.2025b] \\
    \autocite{three} & [Delta.2025] \\
  \end{tabular}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [Bravo.2025a]//[Bravo.2025b]//[Delta.2025]]

If the new options `nohashothers=true, nosortothers=true,` are dropped from the MWE then the code will work even in the current version of `biblatex`. But since the "et al." cannot be properly ignored, this can lead to problems with authors who wrote a work without co-authors and another work with co-authors.

Comment: First version is exactly what I needed. (I still have no idea how to modify the code myself if I need to change it later, but that's my fault, not yours.)