# Tex Studio not running bibtex

Tags: bibtex, texstudio

I can manually run bibtex, but how do I setup Tex Studio's PDF Chain to include `bibtex`?
Tex Studio on my Windows machine works fine.

Comment: Open `Options` → `Configure TeXstudio` In the tab that opens change the field for `build & View` (under Meta Commands) as: `txs:///compile | txs:///bibliography | txs:///compile| txs:///compile | txs:///view`  (By default it will read: `txs:///compile | txs:///view`.  Give `OK` and exit. Now use the double arrow (Build & View) to compile.

Comment: Or use `arara`. Using Latexmk` is also one possibility.

Comment: @Harish:  Thanks. Your first comment works fine.  It refers to the double arrow.  Which option modifies the behaviour of the single arrow?  (Also, if you post it as an answer, I will accept it.)

Comment: Please mention the need to select `Advanced Options`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In TeXstudio, open `Options` and then `Configure TeXstudio`. This opens:

[image]

In this window, check the `Show Advanced Options` at the lower left corner. Now, in `Build` tab, the first field (under `Meta Commands`) `Build & View` has this argument:

```
txs:///compile | txs:///view
```

Change it to

```
txs:///compile | txs:///bibliography | txs:///compile| txs:///compile | txs:///view
```

This is for running `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex` and then `View`.

Press `OK` and exit.

Now pressing double arrow (as shown below) in TeXstudio should do the job.

[image]

For single arrow (i.e., `Compile`) you should change the second one as shown in this picture:

[image]

Comment: One can also see the User commands for `arara` and `makeglossaries` in the first picture.

Comment: Could you explain how the "Repeating" button works (in your screenshot, the Default Compiler line, the repeating button is on. I think it should help in simplifying the build chain we define, i.e. instead of 5 items on the chain, we only need 3?