# Typesetting and Engine settings that can help improve compile time?

Tags: compiling, texshop, performance

Are there any specific options that I can enable or disable to improve compiling time ? I don't understand most of what is included in the settings so I can't decide on my own (new LaTeX user here).

For example, I recently learned that adding `% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk` at the start of the document automatically compiles twice to display the PDF. So maybe there are other quirks that I don't know of that can assist compiling speed instead ?.

These are the settings I have in TexShop Editor :

[image]

[image]

[image]

And the documents starts with :

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=3.81cm,tmargin=2.54cm,rmargin=2.54cm,bmargin=2.52cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.5}
```

Comment: Off-topic: If you are simply trying to get 1.5X spacing, you are probably better off using the package `setspace`, though `\linespread` does have its place.  (Can't help with the speed question.  As far as I know, pdfTeX is appreciably faster than LuaTeX, and I don't really use XeTeX.  You might want to search for questions related to dumping formats; but this is not a beginner topic.)

Comment: Related [Speeding up LaTeX compilation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8791/15717) and it's linked questions at right

Answer (score 1):

Your should check it on your own computer, but compiling from a command line may reduce the time noticeably.

Comment: How do I compile from the command line ?? I always press CMD+T (custom key mapping) to typeset.

Comment: Roughly speaking: <name of the compiler> (e.g. latex, pdflatex) <name of your file> [options]. All in the present directory.

Comment: @NLed And if you not familiar with the command line, here http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-to-the-mac-os-x-command-line is one of tutorials for Mac OS.

Comment: Since TeXShop just runs the same command, I see no reason to expect doing it manually to be any faster. I use TeXShop, and I've always found it to be plenty fast (this is on an iMac that's several years old), except for documents with lots of TikZ pictures. And the solution to that is to save the figures as images to include.