# Goto or jump command in LaTeX?

Tags: debugging

The answer to this is probably "no", but I just wanted to make sure... (also, I'm not trying to get into the whole "gotos are evil" debate `:)`).

Basically, one of the things that irritates me in my current workflow, is that eventually I get to a point where I'm on page 34, and there are a ton of images in the previous 33 pages; so if I get stuck with something on page 34, requiring multiple texing, I have to wait for all of the 33 pages to get done texing first (and this can take a while), before I can see the results of interest.

So I thought, it would have been awesome, if LaTeX (rather, for me currently, `pdflatex`) supported a sort of a "jump" or "goto" command, which I could use like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

% ...

% probably something like this would be needed - pseudo:
\declareGotoMarker{\myjumplabelA}

\begin{document}

% at this point, I'm not interested in the content from 
% start to page 33 - so I'm issuing a jump command 
% right at the document start:

\JumpGoto{\myjumplabelA}

% here content of skipped pages 

% ...

% here is the label, the tex processor  
% should jump to, and continue from:

\myjumplabelA

\section{My page 34 section}

Here there is some content that I'm texing:

A test: \problemcommand

...

% here is end of the snippet that I care about texing at the moment;
% don't need a jump here - can just use \stop etc to exit prematurely:

\stop

% here content continues, to end of doc;
% but I won't be seeing it in PDF, as I issued 
% \stop just previously: 

\section{My page 45 section}

Here some more content, which I'll eventually tex - but not now...

...

\end{document}
```

Well, I guess the code speaks for itself - the desired output would be a PDF with the content, corresponding to pg 34-44 of the original document. Obviously page numbers, and page and some of the other (section, equation, etc.) references will not be available/working when doing this kind of "jump"-shortened run, but that is understood without saying; the goal of this is more-less to assist with troublesome snippets in large documents, without the need (or despite it) to separate content in section files, and then commenting the `\input` lines selectively.

Anything like that within the `pdflatex` world?

Comment: Well, it is not precisely what you want to achieve, but what about the `\includeonly` command?

Comment: Thanks, @Christian - didn't know about `\includeonly`, and that would be useful if you already are keen on commenting includes. My problem is I have not that many separate section files, but they in themselves are huge - and this would require me to split them, which simply complicates matters for me; a `goto` command would save me the hassle, without the need to rearrange files. Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: I am also no enlighted by splitting into files, otherwise, I have no other idea about `goto` commands within `LaTeX` in order to 'omit' some text not relevant for current editing

Comment: Use the comment package.

Comment: @Christian the other problem with `\includeonly` is that it works on `\include`, and therefore the file to be `\include`d is surrounded by page breaks, meaning that you would need to comment out a document part (chapter probably) that aligns with the document structure when this is rarely what's needed. I'm sure you know this, but wanted to present the flip side to your useful suggestion.

Comment: @ChrisH: Yes, I know, there is a pagebreak, but I recently learned from another user that there is package `newclude` preventing the newpage. See one of my recent answers, I can't link it at the moment, it is something called 'dividing into files'

Comment: Due to the way TeX is designed internally, I don't think this one's possible *as asked*. Once a token has been processed, *that's it*.

Comment: See also answer in [compiling - Speeding up LaTeX compilation - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136013/250119)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would load the `comment` package and use its `comment` environment.

Place all the code you want to exclude inside the `comment` environment, that is replace `\JumpGoto{\myjumplabelA}` with `\begin{comment}`  and `\myjumplabelA` with `\end{comment}`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{lipsum} % only for the example

\begin{document}

This is printed.

\begin{comment}
This is not printed

\lipsum[1-15]
\end{comment}

\section{My page 34 section}

Here there is some content that I'm texing:

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

If you then want to print what is inside the `comment` environment you just have to add the line

```
\includecomment{comment}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer @karlkoeller - I was a bit afraid of `comment` because of the effect of opening and closing environments, but I just tried it, it works. Two things: don't break environments' nesting (e.g. `\begin{itemize} \item{x} \begin{comment} ... \end{itemize} ... \begin{itemize} \item{y} \end{comment} \item{z} \end{itemize}` will fail); don't _change_ `\begin{` to `\includecomment{` (fails) - as post says, _add_ `\includecomment{` before `\begin{comment}`. Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: @sdaau: is that fantasy nesting of environments going to work _anywhere_? -- it's surely not a special constraint of `comment.sty`

Comment: Looks like the current version of `comment` package already support that. (`comment` environment in `verbatim` package supports too)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `verbbox` to stuff unwanted content into a verbatim box (that is not typeset).  To undo it, comment out the `\begine{verbbox}` and `\end{verbbox}` commands.  Note from the output, though, that the commented comment is as if it never existed, including section divisions, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{First}
\begin{verbbox}
\lipsum[1-12]
\section{Second}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{verbbox}
\section{Third}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, @StevenBSegletes - never heard of `verbbox` before, good to know about it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Nobody seems to know the package `ifthen`!
Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\optionaltext}{1}%
%or: \newcommand{\optionaltext}{0}%
My mandatory text.
\ifthenelse{\equal{\optionaltext}{1}}{%
  Optional line 1.
  Optional line 2.
  etc.
}{}%
Further mandatory text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's because the package has been deprecated (if memory serves) :)

Comment: Why not use the standard TeX `\if\else\fi` commands in this instance, though?  Ends up being much clearer IMO.

Comment: Oh!! And welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. :)

Comment: @SeanAllred Not deprecated, just that many people prefer to use the expandable logic in `etoolbox`.

Comment: @JosephWright I suppose memory does *not* serve me today :)

Comment: The reason why this is not an option is those final braces. You will definitely loose them after a page and quickly see that it is impossible to keep track.

Answer (score 0):

When using memmoir class, there is a very useful feature that I find more powerful than what I think I could do with GOTO. See newcomment, commentson, and commentsoff, below.

```
\documentclass{memoir}%
\newcomment{printme} % declaration
\commentson{printme} % no need to do anything with this line
\newcomment{printtoc} % declaration
\commentson{printtoc} % no need to do anything with this line

\begin{document}
\commentsoff{printme} % <-----   THIS, COMMENT AND UN-COMMENT
%\commentsoff{printtoc} % <-----   THIS, COMMENT AND UN-COMMENT

\begin{printtoc}
\tableofcontents
\end{printtoc}

\begin{printme}
\chapter{Templates Improve Throughput}
Frequently I need the same set of helper commands so I put them in templates below end of document. The pluses and minuses are simply to attract my attention until the final compile. You can have many task-unique print commands. Definitions can be in preamble or main body. These behave decently well with the subfiles package.
\end{printme}

\end{document}
\begin{printme}\let\clearpage\relax ---   +++ \\
\end{printme}\par ---   +++    \par
\begin{printtoc}\let\clearpage\relax ---   +++  \\
\end{printtoc}\par ---   +++   \par
```