# Why doesn't LaTeX compile faster?

Tags: performance, tex-general

Looking at what computers can do when it comes to presenting graphics (think games, graphical user interfaces, and so forth), it almost comes of as a surprise to me that I often have to wait for several minutes for complex LaTeX files with a lot of tables and figures to compile.

Why doesn't LaTeX compile faster? Is there some theoretical bottleneck when it comes to typesetting systems? Is it dependent on old code that can't be made to run faster without rewriting it completely? Haven't optimization been the focus of the developer team?

Comment: I think you are installing packages on the fly everytime you compile.

Comment: TeX is pretty fast on 'plain' text, and the LaTeX format doesn't add a lot to that: on a modern system you'll output several pages per second. Once you start doing complex calculations *in macros*, things get a bit more tricky. But without an idea of the type of document you are talking about, it's hard to say.

Comment: Remember that Kunth optimised TeX as much as possible to make it workable *at all* on late 1970s machines (minutes per page, of course), and the LaTeX kernel is highly-optimised based on resources available in 1994-ish.

Comment: LaTeX’s speed on today’s machines is as impressive as any other program’s, if you take into due account the huge amount of processing it has to do, being a (pseudo-)language entirely based on macro expansion.  I remember the epic days (mid-90s) when the list of the outputted pages `[1] [2] [3] [4]`… looked like a worm slowly making his way across OzTeX’s window on my 68k-powered Macintosh Classic (bought in 1992) at the pace of roughly one page per minute…  And there was no Ti*k*Z in those years!

Comment: Get a couple cryptocoin-mining GPUs  :-)

Comment: @TeXnician 's answer explains why TeX is sometimes slow but may not answer the question you would rather ask: "how do I spend less time waiting for TeX?". An answer there may be workflow. You can precompile images. You can break a large document in pieces and compile (e.g. book chapters) and use include to compile just what you are working on at the moment.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft And that would help you exactly nothing for your TeX run (see the linked answer on GPU acceleration) :)

Comment: unless your document has thousands of pages it is rather rare, but not impossible, for it to take minutes to run. Hard to guess what is causing the time delay in your document since you give no information, it is certainly not normal.

Comment: You could ask the same question about MS Word. Why is it so bloated and slow? This is hardly a unique problem.

Comment: @jpmc26 I do ask myself the same question about MS Word actually :)

Comment: @GuM If I compare an old computer game from the mid-90s with a modern computer game, I'd say that the perceived difference is several orders of magnitude larger than the difference in LaTeX processing speed. Compare, for example, Battle Arena Toshinden (which was released for Playstation in 1995) with Battlefield V.

Comment: @David Carlisle The exact time isn't really important here. I can simulate whole 3D worlds on my PC instantly when playing a game; in my mind I should be able to create several thousand documents a second. I mean, nobody would say: "So Witcher 3 is running at 0.05 fps for you? Hmm.. Are you maybe trying to fight too many dragons at the same time?" :)

Comment: @TeXnician  life is just plain unfair :-) :-)

Comment: @Speldosa [This comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/compsci/comments/5spho5/is_wirths_law_true_software_is_getting_slower/ddh18v7/) pretty much has the answer.

Comment: @Speldosa can you even _copy_ several thousand documents a second on your filesystem (tex uses and creates a lot of files and often file IO is a major factor, comparing a game running on a gpu with no file IO isn't really useful)

Comment: Related question: [compiling - Speeding up LaTeX compilation - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8791/speeding-up-latex-compilation)

Comment: Some interesting comment I see around https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/647814/is-there-a-fast-latex-compiler#comment1614558_647814

Answer (score 32):

The "slow" compilation speed of TeX has two main reasons:

- It cannot parallelize. Games, GUIs etc. (what you refer to) do use multi-threading to speed up their execution. Because TeX builds up pages gradually (with counters, …) this is not an option and there are some questions about this aspect on the site (see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/181305/124577)), apart from those asking about using the GPU (see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/409232/124577)).
- TeX is a macro expansion language. This kind of "programming" is not necessarily the fastest, but the developers (not engine-wise, but format-wise) try hard not to impose any slow-downs here. That's why some kernel code looks a bit cryptic. And concerning the engines optimization is one of the main concerns.

Just to back up the second point: A primary cause of slow compilation is the general understanding what TeX should do for you. Whenever you load PGF/TikZ or pstricks or something along these lines you essentially use TeX for something it has not been designed for. TeX should do mathematical and text typesetting (and it does that well), it should not produce complex graphics with shadows, draw ducks, plot functions or anything like this. There is a reason TikZ support externalization because this reduces the computations the macro layer has to do on each run.

At some point in history, there were attempts to write a modern TeX engine (NTS, ExTeX, …) – those two in Java – which should be fast and maintainable. But even these "modern" engines are single-threaded and cannot compete with the Web/C driven engines in terms of performance. Even LuaLaTeX as "modern real-world" engine cannot compete with pdflatex on simple documents.

Comment: I don't think ExTeX was ever meant to compete in performance terms with the WEB/Web2c: Knuth's code is _fast_.

Comment: @JosephWright You're right, I edited that part to express that they should implement modern concepts and even they did not make the engines faster.

Comment: I understand that it was probably due to '90s hype around java, but hey, that's not the right language if you want your reimplementation of TeX to run fast! XD

Comment: @gigabytes The aim wasn't to make it run faster

Comment: @gigabytes (a) ExTeX has been in the 2000s (in development till 2011 iirc) and (b) its design is not that bad. The overall aim was to create an easily extensible (modular) typesetting system based on TeX. ExTeX should have been able to deal with pdfLaTeX, Omega and a few other primitives, but as far as I know it never made the jump into the real compiler world.

Comment: Would it not be possible to parallelize and use several processors to build the different graphics built with tikz in a document? Is this feasible today?

Comment: @AndréC Yes, you can use parallelization for externalized TikZ graphics (that's what TikZ actively encourages by providing the make target). But this is an extra step before compiling, it won't affect the speed of the main compilation (apart from not building the graphics due to the reduced amount).

Comment: I think this explanation is wrong: the gradual building of pages isn’t at all the reason that LaTeX can’t be parallelised. In fact, you *could* trivially lay out independent paragraphs, their layouting is mostly completely independent. The major issue is instead that *any* piece of code can redefine subsequently used macros in such a way that would completely change their layouting. That being said, this could still be parallelised by performing speculative layouting and redoing the layout in the (exceedingly rare) cases that previous code changes any macro’s meaning.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I would not call that trivial, especially considering that your independent paragraphs may themselves break pages, making it necessary for such a parallel run to know about even/odd pages and many other oddities. What I meant was the point with the counters as an example of code that does change unexpectedly (think about roman page numbers followed by arabic ones). Concerning speculative layouting I agree that this would be an interesting approach and it would be interesting to see some research on this (do you know about any?).

Comment: @TeXnician I don’t know about anything like this being done for TeX but other layouting engines use something similar routinely (e.g. HTML). TeX is harder due to the redefinition problem (and, yes, counters, page breaks etc) but these are, in the end, all details. Implementing this would certainly be an interesting project.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I know about HTML and CSS rendering in that respect, but the nature of page-based output makes it quite hard. I have just seen [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153131), but maybe this thought deserves a separate answer, what do you think?