Could one hypothetically parallelize LaTeX compilation using \include statements?
I believe I understand the reason why LaTeX/TeX compilers are single threaded. I have a very limited knowledge of typesetting, but I can see the issue. However, surely if \include ensures a \clearpage before and after the included content to avoid intersections with the other parts of the document one could write a document using \include and then parallelize compilation?
I apologise if this is too theoretical of a question for this forum, but I'm interested to learn more about LaTeX and typesetting in general. I just want to know if it's theoretically possible so I could take a stab at it if it is.

related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181305/latex-compilers-with-parallel-support

A later part still relies on the state of counters like the page and section counter, and those you only completely know once the previous part of the document is compiled, hence you still can't parallelise those parts.

Apart from TeX being what it is implemented as a hand coded loop full of global variables, the pdf format itself makes  parallel generation tricky as it consists of many global identifiers and reference specified by byte offsets within a single file. I would say it is theoretically impossible while having a system that is enough like the current system to be called ???tex

also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1989/speed-up-compilation-by-pre-compiling-chapters-separately

The contents of different chapters can affect one another.E.g.,page numbers, \nameref-references to chapter titles, entries for appendices like index or glossary, entries for table of contents, list of figures and pdf bookmarks. For parallelization information about what affects what in which ways needs to be available for all parallel threads simultaneously or you need threads that can interact so that one thread waits until information created by another thread is available.

In TeX stages of defining macros for providing information needed for subsequent typesetting and stages of doing the typesetting can be intertwined. When you attempt to parallelize, then you need to figure out carefully how to ensure that the order of intertwining stages of providing information for subequent typesetting and doing the typesetting is preserved as otherwise there might be threads where information needed for subsequent typesetting is not available as providing that information ended up in another thread.

You would need threads that can interact and that are managed by some sort of supervisor so that it can be handled out across thread what stages of providing information refer to what stages of doing actual typesetting.

I can imagine hypothetically parallelize TeX compilation. But I don't know any such implementation.
Suppose that we want to create a large book with many chapters, each chapter starts on separate page. Then we can run a TeX thread on each chapter individually. The output of such a thread is a queue of boxes 255 use in the output routine. I.e. the threads work with simplified output routine which gets box 255 and puts it to the queue. Finally, after all threads end, the final process runs specific output routine designed for the book (header, footer etc.) and it gets already prepared boxes 255 from first queue, then boxes 255 form second queue etc.
We can see that this concept is memory demanding because almost all typesetting material must be saved in the mentioned queues. Note that classical TeX was designed to be able to keep only single page of the document in its memory: When the page is created (including decorations from output routine) then \shipout primitive is performed and the memory is freed.
The question is whether this is usable to do such a parallelizing. Maybe, more usable should be to try to parallelize processing Tikz pictures in the document, for example. I.e. threads can create a outputs of all Tikz pictures individually and main process gets the results of these threads.

It should certainly be possible to use intermediate storage in a file, and/or just have as many threads at a time as data is fitting. E.g. run chapter 1-5 in parallel, and while chapter 1 is then shipped to the output, you can already start chapter 6.
