# TeXstudio slow compilation

Tags: compiling, texstudio

Using command:
    `Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode 
    "Skripsie".tex`

Compilation in TeXstudio takes very long (3-5 minutes). The document is only 12 pages long with no images. Is there any way to speed it up. Like for example only compiling separate chapters?

Comment: How long does it take to process the same document through a command window/terminal? What platform are you on, what latex distribution? (Windows/mac/linux, miktex/texlive/mactex...)

Comment: HI @FredrikJohansson, I am new at this - what do you mean by command window/terminal? I am on Windows and miktex

Comment: assuming your file is called myfile.tex, try the following: open the folder where the file is stored. Hold down `shift` and right-click on the folder background. You should now get a list with an option *open command window here*. Choose this. In the window type `pdflatex myfile.tex` and see how long this takes.

Comment: Thanks @FredrikJohansson, I did this. It only took a few seconds to process through the command window.

Comment: Do you have many bibliography references? Or create an index?Is the file in a networked folder (I.e. not in a local folder)? If no, then I'd actually recommend that you uninstall and reinstall texstudio to see if that fixes things. Since pdflatex seems to work as expected in a command window, I'd say the problem is with TeXstudio.

Comment: @FredrikJohansson, There is my problem! I do have more than >100 bibliography references and the folder was saved on dropbox desktop. I moved the folder to a local folder and unincluded my bibliography now it compiles much quicker. But I will have to include the bibliography. Is there no way to speed it up if you have so many references?

Comment: take a look at the following link, see if any info there helps. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8791/speeding-up-latex-compilation

Comment: You did two things at once: 1) moved to a local folder 2) removed the bibliography. Which one of these was causing the problem?

Comment: Using [that answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8792/67042) in TexStudio: `Settings > User Commands`, add `pdflatex -draftmode %.tex |
biber % --output-safechars | pdflatex -draftmode %.tex | pdflatex -synctex=1 %.tex | txs:///view`