# Is there a way to compile faster? e.g.: No loading figures

Tags: memoir

I am editing a book and it has quite a lot of figures....I believe this is the reason why it takes long to compile.

I have to do some editing in the text, so I do not need it to load the figures for now...is there a way to do a lean compiling?

Comment: \documentclass[draft]{memoir}`, perhaps?

Comment: Another way: use a switch that defines `\includegraphics` to do nothing at all

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8791/15036

Comment: Consider using `\includeonly` in general for large documents.

Comment: are the figures all pulled in with `\includegraphics`, or are some of them built within the job (e.g. with `tikz` code)?  if the latter, things become a little more complicated, and we need a compilable example to figure out what might work best.

Comment: Yes, all of them `\includegraphics.`

Comment: Related: [Speeding up LaTeX compilation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8791/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning `\includegraphics`: Either use the `draft` class or `graphicx` package option or drop the action of `\includegraphics` into litter bin such that it does nothing.

The `\foreach` loop is just use to 'blow' up the document's size and compilation time.

```
\documentclass{memoir}% or \documentclass[draft]{memoir}


\usepackage{graphicx}% 
\usepackage{pgffor}


\newif\ifdropfigures  % At the time of definition it is false!
\dropfigurestrue % yes, we drop figures
%\dropfiguresfalse
\ifdropfigures
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
}% Ok, `\includegraphics does nothing any longer
\fi

\begin{document}
This is the output:

\foreach \x in {1,...,1000} {%  1000 times doing nothing. 
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ente}
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: What about the demo option if you don't care about the size of the image?

Comment: @daleif: Another option, of course. I had it in mind, but the black boxes aren't really nice

Comment: Might not be, but (1) users don't have to add code, (2) it is faster than draft, as draft still have to read the image to get the dimensions (AFAIR)

Answer (score 2):

The memoir class can be loaded with the option `draft`. It also provides the macro `\ifdraftdoc`, which executes different code depending on whether you are in draft mode or not. You could write a macro making use of this to insert your figures, something along the lines of

```
\newcommand{\insertfigure}[1]{%
    \ifdraftdoc
         \fbox{Placeholder for figure #1}%
    \else
         \includegraphicx{#1}%
    \fi%
}
```