# How can I debug LuaTeX error `referenced object has wrong type`?

Tags: errors, luatex

[Experimenting with custom `LaTeX` formats with `luatex`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/324559/8425), I get that error (not when generating the format):

> ```
> ! error:  (pdf backend): referenced object has wrong type others; should be obj
>
> !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
> ```

I'd like to know what is the cause of that error. The `.log` file does not say more. How can I investigate?

Comment: add \tracingall and see what it was doing, just before it stopped.....