# Pre-built preamble with LuaLaTeX and microtype

Tags: luatex, compiling, microtype, compilation-error, directlua

I have been trying to get super-fast compiles with LuaLaTeX by using a pre-built preamble for my documents. However, every time I try to compile, I get this error:

```
No file main.aux.
[\directlua]:1: attempt to index global 'microtype' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
MT@ifstreq ...{microtype.if_str_eq([[#1]],[[#2]])}
                                                  endcsname
l.3 \begin{document}

?
```

This is with the following MWE:

```
% in pream.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arno Pro}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\endofdump

% in main.tex
\title{Test Document}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
  \blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

To generate the format I used

```
lualatex -ini -jobname="pream" "&lualatex" mylatexformat.ltx """pream.tex"""
```

and to compile `main.tex` I used

```
lualatex -fmt pream """main"""
```

Now, I have [seen on the luatex-dev mailing list](http://tug.org/pipermail/lualatex-dev/2016-May/001656.html) (linked to from Google) that the issue is that `microtype` is attempting to use some Lua code, but it can't because Lua code cannot go into a format – it must be run ‘live’ in the normal way.

Robert from the mailing list suggests putting `\directlua{require("microtype")}` into the document, but does not specify *which one* to put it in. Besides, wouldn't putting it into `main.tex` negate the whole (well, some of it) purpose of doing this – pre-loading all packages so compiles are faster?

Anyways, I digress.

Thanks for all the help you guys always offer here on TeX.sx!

Comment: You also cannot `\setmainfont{Arno Pro}` in a format.

Comment: @HenriMenke Why not? The output says `54 preloaded fonts`.

Comment: Because the font loader uses Lua as well.

Comment: @HenriMenke Oh. Do I have any hope of pre-building this preamble then?

Comment: You can prebuild `\documentclass{article}` and `\usepackage{blindtext}` but that is probably “not enough” for you.

Comment: This question is essentially a duplicate of [Guidelines for using mylatexformat with luatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324559/guidelines-for-using-mylatexformat-with-luatex) but it does not have an answer, but the [first comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324559/guidelines-for-using-mylatexformat-with-luatex#comment792899_324559) repeats what I have stated here.  You cannot dump Lua state or OpenType fonts into a format.

Comment: In the `luatex-dev` thread you mention, @JosephWright seems to suggest that there might be something like a solution: _"One can arrange (using bytecode) to save Lua fragments into a format but this is not really a general solution. Thus Lua code has to be loaded `\everyjob`. That's fine provided it's expected, but LaTeX packages tend to be designed on the assumption that they will be loaded 'live'."_ But I have no idea how this would be done practically nor why it wouldn't be a general solution.