# The precompilation with mylatexformat of a beamer document with lualatex fails

Tags: beamer, luatex, format-files

To speed up the `LuaLaTeX` compilation process of my `beamer` file, I tried, to no avail, to use `mylatexformat` like I usually do with `pdfLaTeX`. I am using the following MWE, called `beamer.tex`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Hello}
        World!
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### With `pdfLaTeX`

Executing the following commands:

`pdflatex -ini -jobname="beamer_pdflatex" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx ""beamer.tex""`

`pdflatex -fmt beamer_pdflatex beamer.tex`

produces the correct output, i.e. the format file `beamer_pdflatex.fmt` with the first command and the pdf file `beamer.pdf` with the second one.

### With `LuaLaTeX`

Executing the command

`lualatex -ini -jobname="beamer_lualatex" "&lualatex" mylatexformat.ltx ""beamer.tex""`

correctly produces the format file `beamer_lualatex.fmt`. However, the compilation command

`lualatex -fmt beamer_lualatex beamer.tex`

fails with the following error (the full log is attached below):

`! error:  (pdf backend): referenced object has wrong type others; should be obj`.

Is this fixable? I have tried with the latest version of TeXLive on Debian testing, and with the latest version of MikTeX on Windows 10.

### `.log` file

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020/Debian)  (format=beamer_lualatex 2020.5.11)  11 MAY 2020 17:52
 restricted system commands enabled.
**beamer.tex
(./beamer.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload entry point
Lua module: luaotfload-init 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / initializatio
n
Lua module: lualibs 2020-02-02 2.70 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2020-02-02 2.70 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
Lua module: luaotfload-log 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / logging
Lua module: luaotfload-parsers 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / filelist
Lua module: luaotfload-configuration 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / conf
ig file reader
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /home/victor/.texlive2020/texmf-var/
luatex-cache/generic-dev/names.
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader “fontloader-2020-01-26.lua” from kpse
-resolved path “/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader
-2020-01-26.lua”.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@state = 6
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 7
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 8
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version “3.11”
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Lua module: luaotfload-loaders 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / callback h
andling
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-database 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / database
Lua module: luaotfload-unicode 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / Unicode he
lpers
Lua module: luaotfload-colors 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 9
Lua module: luaotfload-resolvers 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / resolver
s
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /home/victor/.texlive2020/texmf-var/
luatex-cache/generic-dev/names.
Lua module: luaotfload-features 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / features
Lua module: luaotfload-letterspace 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-embolden 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-notdef 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-harf-define 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / databa
se
Lua module: luaotfload-script 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / Script help
ers
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' at position 1 in `find_truetype_file'.
Lua module: luaotfload-harf-plug 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / database
Inserting `Harf pre_output_filter callback' at position 1 in `pre_output_filter'
.
Inserting `Harf wrapup_run callback' at position 1 in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `Harf finish_pdffile callback' at position 1 in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `Harf glyph_info callback' at position 1 in `glyph_info'.
Lua module: luaotfload-auxiliary 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / auxiliar
y functions
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-fallback 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / fallback
Lua module: luaotfload-multiscript 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / multis
cript
Lua module: luaotfload-tounicode 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / tounicod
e
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 6 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
. L3 programming layer <2020-04-06>
==============================================================================
JOB NAME         : "beamer"
CUSTOMISED FORMAT: "beamer_lualatex"
PRELOADED FILES:
  beamer.cls    2019/09/29 v3.57 A class for typesetting presentations
beamerbasemodes.sty    
etoolbox.sty    2019/09/21 v2.5h e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
beamerbasedecode.sty    
   ifpdf.sty    2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
beamerbaseoptions.sty    
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
  size11.clo    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
graphicx.sty    2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  luatex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for luatex
  pgfsys.sty    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
  pgfrcs.sty    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
pgfrcs.code.tex
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
atbegshi.sty    2019/12/05 v1.19 At begin shipout hook (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.24 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
hyperref.sty    2020/01/14 v7.00d Hypertext links for LaTeX
pdftexcmds.sty    2019/11/24 v0.31 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2019/11/29 v3.13 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2020/01/14 v7.00d Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  bitset.sty    2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
 hluatex.def    2020/01/14 v7.00d Hyperref driver for luaTeX
   puenc.def    2020/01/14 v7.00d Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
stringenc.sty    2019/11/29 v1.12 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO)
atveryend.sty    2019-12-11 v1.11 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
beamerbaserequires.sty    
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    
beamerbasefont.sty    
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
sansmathaccent.sty    2020/01/31
scrlfile.sty    2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
beamerbasetranslator.sty    
translator.sty    2019-05-31 v1.12a Easy translation of strings in LaTeX
beamerbasemisc.sty    
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    
beamerbasetitle.sty    
beamerbasesection.sty    
beamerbaseframe.sty    
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    
beamerbaseframesize.sty    
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    
beamerbasecolor.sty    
beamerbasenotes.sty    
beamerbasetoc.sty    
beamerbasetemplates.sty    
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    
beamerbaseboxes.sty    
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    
enumerate.sty    2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    
beamerbasetheorems.sty    
 amsmath.sty    2020/01/20 v2.17e AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2017/10/31 v2.20.4
beamerbasethemes.sty    
beamerthemedefault.sty    
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B

==============================================================================
(mylatexformat)Info: start reading document "beamer"
(mylatexformat)      on input line 3. (\begin{document})
==============================================================================
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-03-12 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count306
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box73
)
(./beamer.aux)
\openout1 = beamer.aux

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 3.

 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.

*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: luatex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: luatex
* paper: custom
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: includehead includefoot 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(28.45274pt, 307.28987pt, 28.45274pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(0.0pt, 273.14662pt, 0.0pt)
* \paperwidth=364.19536pt
* \paperheight=273.14662pt
* \textwidth=307.28987pt
* \textheight=244.6939pt
* \oddsidemargin=-43.81725pt
* \evensidemargin=-43.81725pt
* \topmargin=-72.26999pt
* \headheight=14.22636pt
* \headsep=0.0pt
* \topskip=11.0pt
* \footskip=14.22636pt
* \marginparwidth=4.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count307
\scratchdimen=\dimen277
\scratchbox=\box74
\nofMPsegments=\count308
\nofMParguments=\count309
\everyMPshowfont=\toks45
\MPscratchCnt=\count310
\MPscratchDim=\dimen278
\MPnumerator=\count311
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count312
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks46
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 48
5.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live

))
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box75
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 3.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2019/09/16 v2.46 Cross-referencing by name of section

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count313
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 3.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 3.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 3.

(./beamer.out) (./beamer.out)
\@outlinefile=\write5

\openout5 = beamer.out
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmss/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/cmss/b/n on input line 3.
\symnumbers=\mathgroup6
\sympureletters=\mathgroup7
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmss/b/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/lmss/b/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathsf on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathit on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/lmss/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/lmss/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathtt on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `numbers' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/b/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `pureletters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmss/m/it --> TU/lmss/b/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/b/n --> TU/lmr/b/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmss/b/n --> TU/lmss/b/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/b/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmss/m/it --> TU/lmss/b/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/b/n on input line 3.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-basic-dictionary
-English.dict
Dictionary: translator-basic-dictionary, Language: English 
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-bibliography-dic
tionary-English.dict
Dictionary: translator-bibliography-dictionary, Language: English 
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-environment-dict
ionary-English.dict
Dictionary: translator-environment-dictionary, Language: English 
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-months-dictionar
y-English.dict
Dictionary: translator-months-dictionary, Language: English 
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-numbers-dictiona
ry-English.dict
Dictionary: translator-numbers-dictionary, Language: English 
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-theorem-dictiona
ry-English.dict
Dictionary: translator-theorem-dictionary, Language: English 
) (./beamer.nav)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /home/victor/.texlive2020/texm
f-var/luatex-cache/generic-dev/names/luaotfload-names.luc [1{/var/lib/texmf/font
s/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
\tf@nav=\write6

\openout6 = beamer.nav
\tf@toc=\write7

\openout7 = beamer.toc
\tf@snm=\write8

\openout8 = beamer.snm

! error:  (pdf backend): referenced object has wrong type others; should be obj
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: there a number of lua related things that can not be dumped in a format, see the answer and the comments here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324559/guidelines-for-using-mylatexformat-with-luatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the link. In light of this, recompiling the preamble every time does not sound so bad!