# Build a chapter file and view pdf

Tags: books

I'm in the process of editing chapter files of a book, and was wondering if there was a way to build a chapter file without building the entire book, so I can easily preview it. However, without a preamble, this produces errors when attempting to build, so this isn't easily doable. I could of course include a preamble, but I assume this would cause issues when building the book. I could make a separate "book" containing only the single chapter, but this seems hacky.

So what is the easiest way to build such a chapter file to view its pdf?

Comment: that is what `\include` is designed for, `\include` each chapter and use `\includeonly{intro}` when working on `intro.tex`

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373339/faster-way-to-compile-a-document/373439#373439 could help