# Compiling LaTeX Sections Separately and Including Compiled Versions in Main Document

Tags: compiling

Consider the following document structure:

```
Project
├── Sections
│   ├── section1.tex
│   └── section2.tex
└── main.tex
```

And here is the content of the files:

**Content** of `main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

    \input{Sections/section1.tex}
    
    \input{Sections/section2.tex}
    
\end{document}
```

**Content** of `section1.tex`

```
\section{Section 1}
bla bla bla
```

**Content** of `section2.tex`

```
\section{Section 2}
bla bla bla
```

**Question:** Is it possible to compile the files `section1.tex` and `section2.tex` separately to save computer resources during compilation, and add the compiled versions of `section1.tex` and `section2.tex` to the `main.tex` file?

Comment: use `\include` and then `\includeonly` when working on one section (that does not add the compiled version, it remakes everything when you want a full document, but that is needed anyway to get page numbers and cross references correct

Comment: highest rated q on the site: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include

Comment: To my understanding: no, there seems to be no way to save compile time. However, you may want to try package subfiles (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfiles) to compile sub-files, e.g. for checking or editing purposes.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426422/what-is-best-practice-to-set-up-multi-file-tex-documents