# miktex/pdflatex compile time printout of file data

Tags: pdftex, compiling

People seem to express concern about all the files .aux etc. that are created.  That doesn't bother me, since I can use \nofile to keep them out of the directory with the .tex source file.

My main concern with miktex/pdflatex compilation is that it prints out hundreds of lines of file loading data on the PDFTexify Console.
Does that printing lengthen the compilation time?
If so, is there a way suppress that printout?

Comment: `\nofile` do you mean `\nofiles`? You can't use `\nofiles` by default or latex will not work at all.

Comment: I'm using beamer, and putting \nofiles in the preamble  has stopped the generation of .aux etc. files without problems.    My main concern is stated in the second paragraph of my query.   BTW I am a novice here: is this the way to reply to David Carlisle???

Comment: yes of course `\nofiles` stops the generation of aux files. but then any cross references, tables of countents, long tables, pdf bookmarks etc will not work, as that is what the aux file is for. perhaps in beamer, with a very simple presentation you might be able to get away with that but you are using a very small subset of latex functionality in that case. No to reply to me (in general) you should use `@` then my id (the system will prompt you) although in this case as I was the only person to have commented, it works anyway

Comment: For `pdflatex` in MikTeX there should be a `-quiet` flag to suppress all output, except errors. However, it probably does not influence compilation time significantly.

Comment: (for future readers:) There is also `-batchmode`. However, realistically, if it would improve compilation time, there would be an answer on it in [compiling - Speeding up LaTeX compilation - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8791/speeding-up-latex-compilation) already.