# TeX, LaTeX and friends files optimization or how do you deal with heavy LaTeX files?

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, texlive, compiling

I am typesetting a general report on my research for my group. I have typeset it using LaTeX, generated all the pictures, figures, tables, drawings, etc using LaTeX packages.

However, when I run it on my TeXLive system, it seems the run time is a little too long. I tried to solve all the warnings I reviewing the report text file of my report. Run time is a little better but I still think it is heavy and the whole run (pdfLaTeX + BibTeX + pdfLaTeX + pdfLaTeX) seems to be a little slow.

I know that this may be dependent on the computer configuration or the packages and content of my file. Of course a book with number of pages may be more time demanding than a simple paper.

I want to hear about your systematic procedures which you use to decrease the load of the file you produce.

Could you please share your best practices optimizing your TeX/LaTeX files?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8791/speeding-up-latex-compilation Refer the above for details.

Comment: Thank you @Learninglatex, amazing post. I will read it.