# LuaLaTeX: How to speed up PDF generation?

Tags: luatex, pdf

With `pdflatex`, I used to write `\pdfcompresslevel 0` and `\pdfobjcompresslevel 0` before the `\documentclass` command. This would disable the PDF compression which in turn speeds up the generation of the PDF file.

However, these commands do not seem to work with LuaLaTeX. Is there a way to speed up the generation of the PDF file, e.g., by also disabling compression?

Comment: Have you tried `{\pdfvariable compresslevel}`? See TUGboat, Volume 37 (2016), No. 1. Hans Hagen’s article on LuaTEX 0.90 backend changes.

Comment: Do you have any benchmarks showing that pdf compression slows down the document generation? I highly doubt that this has any effect on speed. My measurements were all within the same range.

Answer (score 8):

I use (in texlive 2022)

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdf_uncompress:
\ExplSyntaxOff
\documentclass{article}
 ....
```

or (with the new pdfmanagement + latex-dev 2022-06-01)

```
\DocumentMetadata{uncompress}
\documentclass{article}
```

to get uncompressed pdf. That works for all engines.

Comment: Ulrike, I don't know what changed, but at the moment I had to require `expl3` instead of `l3pdf` (and not requiring anything, found a defined `\pdf_uncompress:` but missed compression levels along the way).

Comment: @gusbrs l3pdf is gone, it is now in l3kernel, I updated the answer

Comment: That's what I assumed. Thanks! I'm not sure when and why explicitly loading `expl3` is still needed, but it's working good. :)

Comment: @gusbrs one must load expl3 to force the loading of the backend driver as uncompressing is backend dependant (as the question shows ...).

Comment: Got it! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

After `\edef\pdfcompresslevel{\pdfvariable compresslevel}` `\edef\pdfobjcompresslevel{\pdfvariable objcompresslevel}` you have the mentioned commands as in pdfTeX.

However, the speed problem is in LaTeX itself, no in compression PDF. I am using OpTeX with LuaTeX and I don't have problems with speed.