# Reducing LatexMK compilation time for a simple LaTeX document example?

Tags: luatex, latexmk, performance

Suppose I have a simple document like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Suppose I need to use LuaLatex for reasons not worth mentioning here. I can use the `--quiet` flag to decrease compilation time as follows:

`latexmk -lualatex --quiet a.tex`

Other than using the `--quiet` flag, what *else* can I do to improve performance for this simple example?

Comment: get a faster machine? Just use lualatex and not latexmk?  I doubt this question has any reasonable answer as any parts that could possibly be optimised will be the code described as "I need to use LuaLatex for reasons not worth mentioning here."

Comment: on my machine latexmk --luatex is about 50% slower than luatex on this document (probably due to `--recorder`

Comment: You might find some inspiration at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8791/speeding-up-latex-compilation -- which suggestions apply or don't apply to your code is hard to tell without actually seeing your code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle on my machine, compiling with `lualatex` is actually slower, I'm guessing because `latexmk` can suppress all those log messages with `--quiet`, while `lualatex` doesn't appear to be able to do that. With regards to `--recorder`, compiling with `latexmk --recorder` and `latexmk --recorder-` has no impact on the calculation time.

Comment: latexmk is just a script that runs luatex and other things so it is necessarily slower. you can use batchmode on the lustex commandline. recording all file access to an extra file takes time as does checking whether those files have changed which is what latexmk is doing to decide whether 5o run latex again.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle using the `--recorder-` flag (note the minus sign at the end) suppresses all file recording with LatexMK.

Comment: Recent versions of the LaTeX macroshave a hook to the last page of a document (as of the last compile) that gets stored in the .aux file. Latexmk treats this as a cross-reference so will typeset very dimple documents, that could be typeset in a single pass, twice. You can stop this by creating a latexmkrc file that contains the line `$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'aux'} = '@abspage@last';` to tell latexmk to ignore that aux file entry.