# Compile only a given section

Tags: sectioning, compiling

Is there an optionnal argument to compile only a given section ? I would like to write

```
\section[OnlyThisSection]{My section} ...
```

which would allow me to compile only the section I am working on.

It's for a book class. All chapters are in different files, but there are many sections and subsections in each chapter.

Comment: If you have your sections in separate files, you can use [TeXBlend](https://ctan.org/pkg/texblend) to compile particular files.

Comment: Can you a) add which class you use and b) clarify if you have all your code in one file or if you have separate files for your sections.

Comment: To follow up on samcarter, if the section is in a separate file, you can use `\include`/`\includeonly`.  It will introduce a page break at that point in your main document.  (`\section` does have an optional argument, but it does something else.)

Comment: Note that you have to complile the whole document using `\include` before you can start using `\includeonly` to compile specific files.  It uses stored aux files for labels etc.

Comment: @Arthur If you can move your section to a separate file, you could compile only this section via, e.g. the `subfiles` package or the above mentioned `\includeonly`.

Comment: Thank for yout answers. I am already using separeted files, and I am looking for something that do not need change of structure.  I am just looking for a small "hack" to improve my efficiency in wrinting latex, if it is possible !

Comment: Maybe there is some other approach to speed up your compilation. Can you tell us what makes your document slow? Does it have many images?

Comment: this is exactly what `\include` is designed for,

Comment: LaTeX has some packages that might help (or not). I find that the `subfiles` package allows subfiles that, in turn, contain other subfiles. The subfiles do not need to begin a new page in the main document (although they will, if compiled alone). But of course, a subfile has no knowledge of what its numbering should be, because it does not see the non-compiled content. Or, as @DavidCarlisle noted, use `\include` as the direct approach.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz In my experience, even with a lot of experience optimizing things, LaTeX can still be "just slow". I know all of the tricks in [compiling - Speeding up LaTeX compilation - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8791/speeding-up-latex-compilation/), and yet some of the documents can just take minutes to compile.

Comment: @Arthur Can you explain what do you mean by "change of structure"? Do you mean that you don't want to split one file into different files, one for each subsection?

Comment: @user202729, yes I dont want to have a fil per section.

Comment: Compilation is not so long (as I am already using subfiles), but I was thinking that it could be efficient, when just working on a specific section, to just compile this section. And when I work on the next session, juste change a keyword to compile only this new section and so on.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done with my big project is to have a separate file `justOneSection.tex`.  It and my `main.tex` start with the same

```
\documentclass{book}
\input{header}
\begin{document}
```

After that, `main.tex` `\includes` its files, while `justOneSection.tex` `\inputs` just one section.