Compiling slow!
I have slow compiling, I think it is because these following reasons:

I type in Kurdish (Alphabet similar to Arabic), so I have to compile with XeLaTeX.
Including a lot of pdf (graphs) files.

Any suggestions?

There are some approaches detailed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8791/speeding-up-latex-compilation. But the easiest is probably to use \usepackage[draft]{graphicx}, which switches off all the images (remove [draft] for the final version) and to not compile very often.

you could also try luatex instead of xelatex

How long is your document?  How long is it taking to compile?  The other easiest approach is (assuming you have chapters) using \include and \includeonly.

people can only suggest changes to things that you have told us and since you have said nothing about your document or directory layout or anything else that may affect processing speed  (using tabularray package for example) then you can't really have any answer unless you count unhelpful answers like "use fewer pdf files" or "use a different language"

My document would be 1000 pages long or even more. I do not really have deep knowledge about LaTeX. However, I am sure that using \include for these pdfs is the main reason.

@MiryKurd try with [draft] or even faster (but may change the layout) [demo]  if that is faster that answers your question.  But as commented above you don't need to process 1000 pages every time you edit, that makes no sense you only need to check the section you are working on and just do the full document at the end. see \include.
