# Speeding up latex/lua/tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, lua, performance

I have a rather large LaTeX document in that it generates a lot of LaTeX code using lua (small `.tex` file on disk but large amount of generated LaTeX code). It is very slow to compile and takes about 1 hour to do so.

Almost all of the TeX code is generated from a few lua functions. At the moment I bypass most of the code until it is needed but I'm curious if there is some way to speed up the compilation process when rendering the full blown document.

Is there any way to profile the code and possibly speed it up? I'm not sure where the bottleneck is but essentially the (pseudo)code looks like this:

```
latex:
   for i = 1, n {
      \myluafunction{\arg{i}}
   }

lua:
   function myluafunction(arg) { ... tex.print(result) }
```

where `myluafunction` parses arg using lpeg then generates a lot of TikZ code using `tex.print`. The lua code is quite involved. While I haven't tried, I believe one can't use compiled lua code in `lualatex`, and even if so, I'm not sure how much of a difference it would make?

I imagine that the `tex.print`, even of a large amount of code, would be relatively fast?

Obviously there is a lot of geometry being rendered using TikZ. `myluafunction` essentially prints a bunch of LaTeX TikZ commands. Possibly TikZ is the issue here?

Any ideas what generally is the bottleneck and how it could potentially be improved? (would a virtual drive work for the `.aux` files, etc...)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).  You may find [this discussion](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8791/15925) useful; tikz is mentioned as a particular problem.  Also see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204/15925) about profiling.

Comment: This is a little tricky to debug, but i also suspect tikz being the problem here. 1hour is a huge running time for tex. I want to add http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45/how-can-i-speed-up-latex-compilation for how to improve the tikz speed and the hope for you that on christmas eve the luatex crew relased a new version without patches to lua itself. I have already seen a luajittex crop up on github and it's quite likely this feature will hit mainline soon. The speedups reported are apparently quite impressive.

Comment: Also of interest maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18055/possible-to-avoid-re-compilation-of-unmodified-part-of-latex-document?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

I imagine that the bottleneck is in running the `TikZ` code.  However, to empirically check whether it is or not, a possible option would be to do make copies of the files that you're using and add:

```
function makefile(file)
   f = io.open(file,"w")
   f:write("\\documentclass{article}")
   -- you could put the rest of your preamble here, or just copy paste it later
   f:write("\\begin{document}")
end
```

and,

```
function closefile()
   f:write("\\end{document}"}
   f:close()
end
```

to the `lua` portion.  Then, make wrappers:

```
\def\start#1{\directlua{makefile("\luatexluaescapestring{#1}")}}

\def\stop{\directlua{closefile()}}
```

in the `tex` preamble. You could then search/replace `tex.print` with `f:write` and run your file like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*} % or use a .lua file

function makefile(file)
   f = io.open(file,"w")
   f:write("\\documentclass{article}")
   f:write("\\usepackage{...}")
   f:write("\\begin{document}")
end

function closefile()
   f:write("\\end{document}"}
   f:close()
end

--your lua stuff here

\end{luacode*}

\def\start#1{\directlua{makefile("\luatexluaescapestring{#1}")}}
\def\stop{\directlua{closefile()}}

% your other preamble here

\begin{document}
\start{myfile.tex}

% your code

\stop{}
\end{document}
```

Some variation of the above should get you a compilable `.tex` file.  Running it will take the `lua` stuff out of the equation.  Thus, if it takes nearly an hour to compile you know that the bottleneck is on the TikZ side or at least get a feel for how much of the compilation time is actually taken up by running the code as opposed to producing it via `lua`.  If it turns out that the `lua` is taking a significant portion of the compilation time, here are a couple of resources that might help you to speed it up:

http://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf

http://trac.caspring.org/wiki/LuaPerformance

and if you can confirm that TikZ takes too long, you should seriously consider the use of either TikZ's external library or the standalone package. Both can significantly speed-up the processing of documents with many tikz pictures (they are optimized for slightly different use-cases).

Comment: Good answer. Here is a possible way to continue your last sentence: ... and if you can confirm that TikZ takes too long, you should seriously consider the use of either TikZ's `external` library or the `standalone` package. Both can significantly speed-up the processing of documents with many tikz pictures (they are optimized for slightly different use-cases).

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger  Thanks, I've added your suggestion :)