# Instant Compiler for .tex

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling, editors

I am using Overleaf to compile `.tex` files but sometimes it take too much time.

Is there a software that can compile `.tex` files instantly??

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: and [How to speed up LaTeX compilation with several TikZ pictures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45/156344)

Comment: how can any computer program run instantly?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle For that you need to switch off special relativity. That is, uninstall special relativity, and there you go. ;-)

Comment: @marmot Love the idea of a toggle switch OFF for moving from fast to faster and certainly agree unistall will make compilation commands reply instantly "Error: not found" but the correct answer is switch the nitrogen DOWN from cool to supercooled then the CPU can overheat faster

Comment: @KJO The problem is more fundamental. Special relativity prohibits instantaneous action.

Comment: @marmot Always informative I looked up that fountain of all knowledge (Wicky) and it says "Events that occur at the same time for one observer can occur at different times for another." That just about sums my learning ability in TeX I am on the slow side whilst others.....

Comment: @marmot: You are wrong about special relativity. All you need is a tachyon processor, and there will be an inertial frame of reference were the calculations are finished at the same time they are started.