# Include folder with TikZ plots in the preamble

Tags: pgfplots, standalone

I'm writing my PhD thesis and I have just discovered the `matlab2tikz` script for MATLAB so I wanted to convert my plots and put them in the document using `pgfplots`. My thesis is already very big and when I compile it takes a long time so I wanted to make use of the `standalone` package to compile the graphs externally so as to speed up the process. `matlab2tikz` outputs a `.tex` or `.tikz` file with the necessary code, an example is:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw   (23,42) .. controls (23,28.19) and (34.19,17) .. (48,17) .. controls (61.81,17) and (73,28.19) .. (73,42) .. controls (73,55.81) and (61.81,67) .. (48,67) .. controls (34.19,67) and (23,55.81) .. (23,42) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

In this case, I saved the file as a `.tex`. Then, following the instructions of the `standalone` package manual, I modified the file as follows

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw   (23,42) .. controls (23,28.19) and (34.19,17) .. (48,17) .. controls (61.81,17) and (73,28.19) .. (73,42) .. controls (73,55.81) and (61.81,67) .. (48,67) .. controls (34.19,67) and (23,55.81) .. (23,42) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and saved it as `test.tex`. When I try to compile the document, whether I have `\includestandalone[width=\textwidth]{test}` or `\input{test}` I get `Can be used only in preamble` error. I'm sure it has to do with the fact that `test.tex` is not in the main document folder, it's instead in the same folder as all the images. My question is, therefore, this: What should be included in the preamble to point to the folder that contains the files with the TikZ plots? Below is my preamble with a minimal working example:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,english,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[acronym,nopostdot,style=index,nogroupskip,nomain]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{comment,array,url}
\usepackage[font={small,it},center]{caption}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\loadglsentries{D:/Dropbox/NTU/Research/Resources/03_glossary.tex}

\graphicspath{{D:/Dropbox/NTU/Research/Resources/02_All_images/}{}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includestandalone[width=\textwidth]{test}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do not nest `tikzpictures`. *always* set `compat` level when using PGFPlots.

Answer (score 0):

I use a slightly different approach. I save **all** TikZ files only with `\begin{tikzpicture}` and its `\end` and then insert them with `\input{fig_TikZ_name}`. Therefore, the preamble of the main file must have the `\usepackage`s for `tikz` and `pgfplots`.

The message `Can be used only in preamble` appears when a `\usepackage` is inside the `\begin{document}`. To edit those TikZ file I use TikzEdt or a minimal .tex that only inserts the TikZ file I'm editing.

The package `\adjustbox` is just one option to scale the picture, not best, not all-mighty, just useful in many scenarios.

It may still be possible to use the approach with `standalone`, I just don't know how or if it is possible. Sorry for that.

A MWE follows.

fig_TikZ_name.tex file:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[blue, ->]   (0,0) -- (10,10);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Main file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % Can be used only in preamble. \usepackage

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \input{figTikZname}
    \caption{text}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]
    {\adjustbox{width = 0.9\linewidth}{\input{figTikZname}}}
    \caption{adjustbox}
\end{figure}
\input{figTikZname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I also thought of using the same method but from what I understand the problem is that then the TikZ pictures have to be compiled every time I compile the document, whereas using standalone they are only compiled once. Am I wrong as far as you know?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45/140133. Check the answer about the PGF Manual and some of the comments.

Comment: This defies the purpose of OP putting the pictures/figures in separate files

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when you modify generated code. In your case, you have two `\begin{tikzpicture}` but only one `\end{tikzpicture}`.

The correct `test.tex` file should be:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
        \draw   (23,42) .. controls (23,28.19) and (34.19,17) .. (48,17) .. controls (61.81,17) and (73,28.19) .. (73,42) .. controls (73,55.81) and (61.81,67) .. (48,67) .. controls (34.19,67) and (23,55.81) .. (23,42) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I also removed innecesary stuff from your MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,english,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \includestandalone[width=\textwidth]{test}
        \caption{Caption}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This compiles without error.

[image: output]